# SSL socket php code needs to be converted to Java

Tags: java, php, ssl, sockets

I have a Pem file that I use with this php code to connect to a c++ SSL server, but now I need this php code written in Java

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');

stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $pass);

$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://serverURL', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

if (!$fp) {

    print "Failed to connect $err $errstr\n";
    return;
}
```

Any ideas how to read in the cert.pem file in Java and then establish the SSL socket?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

You will need [Bouncy Castle](http://www.bouncycastle.org) in your classpath.

```
PEMReader pr = new PEMReader(new FileReader("cert.pem"));
X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) pr.readObject();
PEMReader kr = new PEMReader(new FileReader("privkey.pem"),
        new PasswordFinder() {
    public char[] getPassword() {
        return "passphase".toCharArray();
    }
});
KeyPair key = (KeyPair) kr.readObject();
KeyStore ksKeys = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ksKeys.load(null, "passphase".toCharArray());
ksKeys.setCertificateEntry("MyCert", cert);
ksKeys.setKeyEntry("Mykey", key.getPrivate(),
        "passphase".toCharArray(), new Certificate[]{cert});
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
        KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmf.init(ksKeys, "passphase".toCharArray());
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(
        TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ksKeys);

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

Socket socket = sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(
        "localhost", 4433);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        socket.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
        socket.getOutputStream()));
out.println("Hello World");
System.out.println(in.readLine());
out.close();
in.close();
```

If you run `openssl s_server -Verify cert.pem -cert cert.pem -key privkey.pem`, it should show:

```
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 /C=AU/ST=Some-State/O=Internet Widgits Pty Ltd
verify return:1
Hello World
DONE
shutting down SSL
CONNECTION CLOSED
ACCEPT
```