# How to use PEM file to create a SSL socket in Java?

Tags: java, ssl, certificate, pem, jks

[See related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722931/ssl-socket-php-code-needs-to-be-converted-to-java)

I have a PEM file provided to me and was told that it will be needed in establishing a SSL socket that connects to a c++ server for some API calls. Does anyone know how I can read in the PEM file and connect? I was also given the parapharse password.

Comment: Duplicate; I think the other version of the question is more informative.

Answer (score 12):

It sounds like the PEM file is a client cert for you to use to login to the server.  If it is the client cert, and it sounds like it is, you will likely need a ca cert file also to use in validating the servers certificate in order to establish a connection.

The CA certs need to go into a truststore and your client certs need to go into a keystore.  In Java, both of these will be JKS (although it has limited support for PKCS12.)  There are default keystore/truststore locations for the JRE as well as for each user.  You can also specify external locations for these files in your code, as in the examples below.  The commons-ssl library seems to be able to support PEM directly, without the need for JKS, but I haven't used it.

The default passphrase for these keystores in Java is "changeit" without the quotes.

[This page](http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/79-AB.html) shows you have to read the PEM into your keystore/truststore.  Here is [another example](http://pa55word.wordpress.com/2009/01/21/how-to-get-your-java-keystoretruststore-from-pem-files/).

Once you have your truststore and keystore set up properly, you need to pass the following [JSSE system properties](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r2/ic2924/index.htm?info/rzaha/rzahajssesysprops.htm) to your JVM:

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore
javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword
javax.net.ssl.trustStore
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword
```

You may specify them as -D parameters to the JRE or, as in the examples below, programatically.

Once you finish that, heres a [commons-ssl example](http://juliusdavies.ca/commons-ssl/ssl.html) of creating a socket.  Also, heres the Java api for [SSLSocket](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html).  Heres also an [example](http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/ssl_socket.html) that doesn't use any apache commons.

Comment: Ahmm.. nice answer - but he actually asked about C++, not Java.

Comment: Actually, he tagged it Java and JKS, which is the Java KeyStore.  He wants to connect to a remote server which will be done using an SSL socket.  The fact that the other side C++ is not so relevant to the connection mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You need a library that handles SSL. As John Ellinwood noted, some frameworks (such as Java 2 SE) offers these built-in, for others you'd need to use 3rd party libraries.

C developers often use openssl directly, but it can't be said to be easy and when using C++ there are several "gotchas" that are easy to fall into.

I suggest you use a C++ network library with support for SSL, such as QT's network library, or Poco NetSSL. See [here](http://www.appinf.com/docs/poco/NetSSL_Schannel.html) for some tutorial documentation [and here](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SSLManager.html) for the API documentation - you probably want to take a look at [initializeClient](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.SSLManager.html#11818) which takes a PEM file directly.