# tell java to accept a self-signed certificate (to some extent a repeated question)

Tags: java, ssl, jsse

Alright, so when I attempt to access the file manager through webmin it fails and throws an error to the tune of:

failed to get language list : javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException : java.sucurity.cert.CertificateException: Java couldn't trust server

So, I read a little bit and found out (I think) that I need to configure java to accept the self-signed certificate. Now,

[telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

This really didn't clear anything up because I'm really not sure that we have the same problem, or if both our problems have the same solution? So, I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction with some articles, possibly tell me what java I need to be configuring (I'm assuming that it is the VMware java?)

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException : java.sucurity.cert.CertificateException: Java couldn't trust server
```

That's not a Java message. You would need to post the actual message of the exception, not something made up by the application. (Never do that.)

To answer the original question, all you have to do is import the certificate into the client's truststore.

See [here](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=9797465#9797465) for a keytool-less way of doing it, with thanks to Andreas Sterbenz.