# scala.xml.Xml load self-signed https

Tags: xml, scala, https

I want to "load" a xml source from a self-signed https server.

```
scala.xml.XML.load("https://....")
```

returns some exception ("untrusted certificate" etc.)

How can I get around that?

Even worse, I need to authenticate with username and password ...

(it's a subversion server ...)

TIA, Sebastian.

Comment: Import the certificate in your trust store.

Comment: Maybe you can try downloading that xml source using standard methods (SSL-capable HTTP libs, try Dispatch for that), and then calling scala.xml.XML.loadString.

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks! For reference I link to a howto: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, google revealed answers (If you only knew the right keywords in advance ...)

This shows howto setup authentication:

http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/events/ScnTwitterBlog.scala

And this discusses self-signed certificates:

[telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Cheers!

Comment: Remember that the options that rely on writing a trust manager that doesn't do anything (Option 2 in the answer you link to) introduce a vulnerability to MITM attacks.