# how to not to verify certificate in ldap ssl connection

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

I'm using novell ldap api and I must use ssl connection but I'm searching for a way in which the client not verify the certificate when connection starts...I get the follow exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I'm try to reproduce the behavior like when I open a web page in https and browser asks me if I want to accept the certificate...
I didn't find any method to do this with novell ldap api and I'm wondering if it is possibile to do in pure java programmatic way. Thanks

G

Comment: Have you tried - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: Why? Why use SSL if you don't care about security?

Comment: I'm agree with you but it's a strange and complicate client's policy..

Comment: [SOLVED] thanks to http://huikaucom.blogspot.it/2006/05/disable-cert-validation-for-ldap-and.html