# Sonar - Fail to request server version

Tags: c++, sonarqube

I am Setting the sonar system for C++ Binaries and i am trying with https Setup.

See the Connector element in Server.xml

```
 <Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" SSLEnabled="true"
     maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="false"
     clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
     keystoreFile="D:/sonar_framework/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/conf/.keystore" keystorePass="changeit"
     ciphers="SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA"/>
```

And sonar.host.url=https://b1.co:8443/sonar/  in Sonar-runner.properties

i gave the localhost also for the next try,

But it shows the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to request server version
        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.getServerVersion(Bootstrapper.java:73)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.checkSonarVersion(Runner.java:220)
        at org.sonar.runner.Runner.execute(Runner.java:150)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:84)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:56)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching <machine Name> found
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1902)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:270)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1341)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:153)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
        at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:748)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContent(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:434)
        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.remoteContent(Bootstrapper.java:125)
        at org.sonar.runner.Bootstrapper.getServerVersion(Bootstrapper.java:71)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching blrkmis1977pc.in002.siemens.net found
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:208)
        at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:93)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:203)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1323)
        ... 18 more
```

help me to resolve this.

Comment: Are you using a self signed cert? Also, the stracktrace is for localhost, do you get one when you don't use localhost, but the full domain name?

Comment: I am using the full domain name also and self signed certified. Still i am facing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to tell Java to accept the self signed cert. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate) SO post (option 1 in the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you should check your sonar server, in your log, you server is using port 8443, so you should use the following command to check is this port still listening??
 netstat -anl | grep 8443

or

you just restart the sonar server.