# Unable to add SSL support for database

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, ssl

I am using Spring3, Hibernate4 and postgres9.2.

For enabling the SSL database connection, I followed following steps :

1. Creating self signed Certificate : refer : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ssl-tcp.html#SSL-CERTIFICATE-CREATION
2. Copied the generated `server.crt` and `server.key` into `postgres/9.2/data` folder.
3. URL for hibernate connection : `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DB_NAME?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`

After restarting the postgres I run my application and it gives error as :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server does not support SSL.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:307)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:105)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:140)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.<init>(Jdbc4Connection.java:23)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
```

Even I tried to add this line at the end of `pg_hba.conf` file but postgres does not get restarted :

```
hostssl     all     all         127.0.0.1/32        trust
```

**EDIT**

It is for other folks who received such error or wants to add database ssl connection :

I added `ssl = true` and removed comments for ssl related entries from `postgresql.conf` and it worked. :)

Comment: Where'd you get your PostgreSQL from? Self-compiled? Make sure that it's really using ssl, check with wireshark or tcpdump and make sure the network traffic isn't in the clear. From your update, are you saying that you had the SSL directives in `postgresql.conf` commented out?

Comment: @CraigRinger Thna you for your suggestion. For cross-checking, I added ssl=false and added comments to ssl related fields from `postgresql.conf` file then it gives error like `Server does not support SSL`. So did I successfully configured SSL ?

Comment: If you read the documentation, you'll see that the mere presence of any value for `ssl` is sufficient to turn it on. So `ssl=false` and `ssl=true` are (rather counter-intuitively) the same thing. What I was asking was what you meant by "added/removed comments for ssl related entries". Do you mean you *commented them out*, and that you originally *forgot to uncomment them*?

Comment: yes. exactly what i mean.. following are the lines which was commented before. and then I uncomment it : `ssl_ciphers = 'ALL:!ADH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:@STRENGTH' 
     
ssl_renegotiation_limit = 512MB 
ssl_cert_file = 'server.crt'  
ssl_key_file = 'server.key'  
ssl_ca_file = ''   
ssl_crl_file = ''   
password_encryption = on
`

Answer (score 4):

The root of your problem appears to be that your server does not support SSL or does not have it enabled. The message:

```
The server does not support SSL
```

may only be emitted by `org/postgresql/core/v3/ConnectionFactoryImpl.java` in `enableSSL(...)` when the server refuses or doesn't understand SSL requests.

Sure enough, in your update you say that *you had the SSL-related options in `postgresql.conf` commented out*. Them being commented out is the same as them being not there at all to the server; it will ignore them. This will cause the server to say it doesn't support SSL and refuse SSL connections because it doesn't know what server certificate to send. PgJDBC will report the error above when this happens.

When you un-commented the SSL options in `postgresql.conf` and re-started the server it started working.

You were probably confused by the fact that:

```
&ssl
&ssl=true
&ssl=false
```

*all do the same thing*: they enable SSL. Yes, that's kind of crazy. It's like that for historical reasons that we're stuck with, but it's [clearly documented in the JDBC driver parameter reference](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/connect.html#connection-parameters):

> *ssl*
>
> Connect using SSL. The driver must have been compiled with SSL
>   support. This property does not need a value associated with it. The
>   mere presence of it specifies a SSL connection. However, for
>   compatibility with future versions, the value "true" is preferred. For
>   more information see Chapter 4, Using SSL.

As you can see, you should still write `ssl=true` since this may change in future.

Reading the [server configuration](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/ssl.html#ssl-server) and [client configuration](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/ssl-client.html) sections of the manual will help you with setting up the certificates and installing the certificate in your local certificate list so you don't have to disable certificate trust checking.

For anyone else with this problem: There will be more details in your PostgreSQL error logs, but my guess is your PostgreSQL config isn't right or you're using a hand-compiled PostgreSQL and you didn't compile it with SSL support.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a self-signed certificate you need to add it to your trusted key store of your Java installation on the client side.

You find the detailed instructions to achieve this here: [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Comment: Thank you Torsten for your response. But I solved this problem and added it at in my question.

Comment: Good to hear. The sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory part is what is saving you from checking the certificate trust chain.

Answer (score 1):

In your connection string, try

```
?sslmode=require
```

instead of

```
?ssl=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Use param **sslmode=disable**. Work for me. Postgresql 9.5 with jdbc driver SlickPostgresDriver.