# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server does not support SSL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql

I am newbie who is just creating a web application and while working with it instead of localhost I put the IP addresss of the computer and changed in every place.I also follwed the below solution [Followed Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25641047/org-postgresql-util-psqlexception-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host) and then also set ssl=on in my postgresql.config.Could anyone tell me where am I should configure to allow ssl? Any help is appreciated.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The server does not support SSL.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:349)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:148)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:215)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:404)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:272)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.dmmsmulta.TaxiVis.dao.mydata.connectToDatabaseOrDie(mydata.java:223)
    at com.dmmsmulta.TaxiVis.dao.mydata.<init>(mydata.java:63)
    at com.dmmsmulta.TaxiVis.controller.HomeController.getDummy(HomeController.java:130)
    at com.dmmsmulta.TaxiVis.controller.HomeController.getCool(HomeController.java:123)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:220)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:134)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are you asking us how to configure the PostgreSQL *Server* for SSL? Did you read and follow the [PostgreSQL manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ssl-tcp.html) on the topic?

Comment: @Andreas No I am asking why is it not allowing to use the IP instead of localhost?Even though I changed  parameter ssl to on in postgresql.conf

Comment: So you're saying that SSL worked when accessed as localhost, but SSL doesn't work when accessed as server name? To check if this is a Java issue or a server issue, can you access with SSL using `pgAdmin` tool?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to add SSL support for database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16980551/5221149)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to proceed:

- Make sure you are connecting to the correct server. This may sound trivial, but is often the cause of problems.
- Set `log_connections = on` on the PostgreSQL server and check the PostgreSQL log file after the failed connection attempt. This should tell you more about the problem.
- Make sure that the correct line in `pg_hba.conf` is used. In recent PostgreSQL versions, the server log entry will tell you which line was used, which can help you to spot configuration issues in `pg_hba.conf`.
- Make sure that OpenSSL is of a reasonably recent version on the PostgreSQL server and you are using a recent JDBC driver. New SSL implementations will refuse to communicate with very old SSL implementation to avoid security flaws in the protocol. The PostgreSQL log line should give you a clue.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to avoid this is to disable ssl when connecting to Postgres database by using the following parameter: ***?sslmode=disable***

```
jdbc:postgresql://${{db_host}}:${{db_port}}/${{your_db_name}}?sslmode=disable&amp;
```

Hope it helps !