# How do I import self-signed certificates in Java SSL safely?

Tags: java, ssl, keytool, self-signed

I'm writing a program to simulate a secure connection over SSL sockets. I want the client to import certificates that are not trusted (and hence not in its truststore) at their own discretion through an interface. These certificates are self-signed.

So far I have hit a wall, where the program crashes and reports `Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown`
due to the fact that the server certificate doesn't reside in the client truststore.

I am simulating the connection locally. I've found examples where truststore managers are used explicitly to override all SSL checking, but this is wide open to MITM attacks.

I need to wrap the truststore manager implementation in some way to make it secure, and ensure server certificates are validated. The link here gives a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate) of an open implementation, but I don't know how to wrap it securely.

In the case of the trustmanager implementation it will still fire a `CertificateException` when it locates an untrusted certificate (from its `checkServerTrusted` method), do I have to handle the exception yet continue execution of the program from there? I'm very unsure  how to tackle this secure wrapping.

Many thanks all

Comment: The thing is that using self-signed certificates is also vulnerable to MITM attacks

Comment: @andrershov Is that part of the underlying Java implementation of the library or the cipher suite type? Ultimately I want to make it more secure than open SSL connections

Comment: Where is a problem, when you're distributing self-signed certificate. There is a risk of MITM attack during distribution. But I agree when the client has a server certificate and he is sure that it's not faked, the connection would be secure

Comment: Yes. I'm mimicking self-signed certificates from trusted and malicious parties. There will be a stage where the client needs to accept a genuine self-signed certificate, but it will originally be untrusted, and that's my dilemma.

Comment: Do you _really_ need to use self-signed certificates? It's quite easy (and free) to obtain a certificate at [CAcert](http://www.cacert.org/).