# SSL-exception in Java when connecting to google analytics api

Tags: java, ssl, google-analytics, ssl-certificate, google-analytics-api

I try to connect to the Google-Analytics-API authenticating via oauth2

When I run the code belowm, then authentication seems to work, but then I get:

```
"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"
```

When coming to this line:

```
Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();
```

I added the certificate of https://www.googleapis.com/ to the `jre7-keystore`, but it is not helping

Does somebody have an idea on what I could do? Is there a way to just accept all certificates?

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except
 * in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the License
 * is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express
 * or implied. See the License for the specific language governing permissions and limitations under
 * the License.
 */



import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.Analytics;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.AnalyticsScopes;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Accounts;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.GaData.ColumnHeaders;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Profiles;
import com.google.api.services.analytics.model.Webproperties;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;



/**
 * This is a basic hello world sample for the Google Analytics API. It is designed to run from the
 * command line and will prompt a user to grant access to their data. Once complete, the sample will
 * traverse the Management API hierarchy by going through the authorized user's first account, first
 * web property, and finally the first profile and retrieve the first profile id. This ID is then
 * used with the Core Reporting API to retrieve the top 25 organic search terms.
 *
 * @author api.nickm@gmail.com
 */
public class HelloAnalyticsApiSample {

  /**
   * Be sure to specify the name of your application. If the application name is {@code null} or
   * blank, the application will log a warning. Suggested format is "MyCompany-ProductName/1.0".
   */
  private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Neckermann-Analytics/1.0";

  /** Directory to store user credentials. */
  private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
//      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/analytics_sample");
        new java.io.File("G:/Programm Daten/GA", ".store/analytics_sample");

  /**
   * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
   * globally shared instance across your application.
   */
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
  private static HttpTransport httpTransport;

  /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private static final String CLIENT_ID = "xxx";

private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "xxx";

  /**
   * Main demo. This first initializes an analytics service object. It then uses the Google
   * Analytics Management API to get the first profile ID for the authorized user. It then uses the
   * Core Reporting API to retrieve the top 25 organic search terms. Finally the results are printed
   * to the screen. If an API error occurs, it is printed here.
   *
   * @param args command line args.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {


      httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
      dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
      Analytics analytics = initializeAnalytics();
      String profileId = getFirstProfileId(analytics);
      if (profileId == null) {
        System.err.println("No profiles found.");
      } else {
        GaData gaData = executeDataQuery(analytics, profileId);
        printGaData(gaData);
      }
    } catch (GoogleJsonResponseException e) {
      System.err.println("There was a service error: " + e.getDetails().getCode() + " : "
          + e.getDetails().getMessage());
    } catch (Throwable t) {
      t.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorize() throws Exception {
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
            httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, CLIENT_ID,CLIENT_SECRET,
            Collections.singleton(AnalyticsScopes.ANALYTICS_READONLY)).setDataStoreFactory(
                    dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  /**
   * Performs all necessary setup steps for running requests against the API.
   *
   * @return An initialized Analytics service object.
   *
   * @throws Exception if an issue occurs with OAuth2Native authorize.
   */
  private static Analytics initializeAnalytics() throws Exception {
    // Authorization.
    Credential credential = authorize();

    // Set up and return Google Analytics API client.
    return new Analytics.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
        APPLICATION_NAME).build();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the first profile id by traversing the Google Analytics Management API. This makes 3
   * queries, first to the accounts collection, then to the web properties collection, and finally
   * to the profiles collection. In each request the first ID of the first entity is retrieved and
   * used in the query for the next collection in the hierarchy.
   *
   * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
   * @return the profile ID of the user's first account, web property, and profile.
   * @throws IOException if the API encounters an error.
   */
  private static String getFirstProfileId(Analytics analytics) throws IOException {
    String profileId = null;

    // Query accounts collection.
    Accounts accounts = analytics.management().accounts().list().execute();

    if (accounts.getItems().isEmpty()) {
      System.err.println("No accounts found");
    } else {
      String firstAccountId = accounts.getItems().get(0).getId();

      // Query webproperties collection.
      Webproperties webproperties =
          analytics.management().webproperties().list(firstAccountId).execute();

      if (webproperties.getItems().isEmpty()) {
        System.err.println("No Webproperties found");
      } else {
        String firstWebpropertyId = webproperties.getItems().get(0).getId();

        // Query profiles collection.
        Profiles profiles =
            analytics.management().profiles().list(firstAccountId, firstWebpropertyId).execute();

        if (profiles.getItems().isEmpty()) {
          System.err.println("No profiles found");
        } else {
          profileId = profiles.getItems().get(0).getId();
        }
      }
    }
    return profileId;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the top 25 organic search keywords and traffic source by visits. The Core Reporting API
   * is used to retrieve this data.
   *
   * @param analytics the analytics service object used to access the API.
   * @param profileId the profile ID from which to retrieve data.
   * @return the response from the API.
   * @throws IOException tf an API error occured.
   */
  private static GaData executeDataQuery(Analytics analytics, String profileId) throws IOException {
    return analytics.data().ga().get("ga:" + profileId, // Table Id. ga: + profile id.
        "2012-01-01", // Start date.
        "2012-01-14", // End date.
        "ga:visits") // Metrics.
        .setDimensions("ga:source,ga:keyword")
        .setSort("-ga:visits,ga:source")
        .setFilters("ga:medium==organic")
        .setMaxResults(25)
        .execute();
  }

  /**
   * Prints the output from the Core Reporting API. The profile name is printed along with each
   * column name and all the data in the rows.
   *
   * @param results data returned from the Core Reporting API.
   */
  private static void printGaData(GaData results) {
    System.out.println(
        "printing results for profile: " + results.getProfileInfo().getProfileName());

    if (results.getRows() == null || results.getRows().isEmpty()) {
      System.out.println("No results Found.");
    } else {

      // Print column headers.
      for (ColumnHeaders header : results.getColumnHeaders()) {
        System.out.printf("%30s", header.getName());
      }
      System.out.println();

      // Print actual data.
      for (List<String> row : results.getRows()) {
        for (String column : row) {
          System.out.printf("%30s", column);
        }
        System.out.println();
      }

      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

And here ist the full stack trace of the exceptions I am getting:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at  com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at HelloAnalyticsApiSample.getFirstProfileId(HelloAnalyticsApiSample.java:194)
at HelloAnalyticsApiSample.main(HelloAnalyticsApiSample.java:123)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
... 18 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid      certification path to requested target
at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
... 24 more
```

Comment: I also tried the unsecure option No 2 in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: According to the accepted answer, there was a firewall issue: off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all the problem was the firewall of the company I am working at. The firewall was somehow changing the http-header. After putting *.googleapis.com on a whitelist it works fine.

Comment: I have the exact same problem , how did you whitelist *.googleapis.com?

Comment: umm... sorry, my answer is not going to help you: I've sent an email to the department in charge of the firewall settings "Please whitelist *.googleapis.com". (I'am not working for that company anymore, so I cannot ask for you, sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we had a very similar complex problem and it turned out to be MacAfee Web gateway (MWG) proxy configuration causing this issue.  We noticed a strange behavior of the SSL certificate validation where it works from one process and gives an error from another process. It worked from straight command line Java execution but gave an error when we ran the same code through a container.  We imported all the certs from accounts.google.com  and *.googleapsi.com. We were clue less on what to do.

It looks that MacAfee Web gateway (MWG) proxy white list configuration is based on the client process(exe or script) name.  MWG has default configuration to white list all HTTPS URLs for  Java.exe process but not for other process (exe) names such as container(odi.exe).   Because of this setting in MacAfee Web gateway proxy the command line Java code worked successfully and the same code from container gave error.  We also noticed that if there is a proxy issued SSL cert for the HTTPS URL then SSL cert validation worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking on .store/analytics_sample on the https URLs, the authorization URL, your callback URL and the authorization token URL have some SSL certificate that is not valid.

The main point is the error is due to untrusted SSL certification that Java throws.