# Java : How import a certificate?

Tags: java, validation, security, ssl

I have developed two simple java programs : a SSL client and a SSL server which have to communicate on a LAN, with a one-way authentication.

Right now I am running the client and the server on the same computer.

My questions are about certificates :

I've managed to create a `.jks` and `.crt` thanks to the keytool in `jdk\bin`.

In `server.java`:

`myKeyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keyStoreName), keyStorePassword);`

... and I don't know how import the certificate inside the client.

When I tried to run both this is what I got on the client side:

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

...

`Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

...

`Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Comment: You probably have a self-signed certificate (or did you buy a certificate from a CA?). See, for example: [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Comment: I created a self-signed certificate, then a keystore. 
Then I export this certificate from the keystore and added this certificate to the java CA (`jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\security\cacerts`)

But it still won´t accept the connection

Comment: You import a certificate with the keytool. The error means you haven't.

Comment: Ok, I must import the certificate in the cacerts in jdk1.7.0_75\jre\lib\security\cacerts, right ?