# Connect to ssl web socket as a client on wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/:pair

Tags: java, websocket, jetty-9, java-websocket

I am trying to connect to wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/:pair

Instructions are at https://www.luno.com/en/api towards the bottom of the page

I have successfully run the accepted answer from [Connecting to a secured websocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29189197/connecting-to-a-secured-websocket)

However when I replace the url

```
String url = "wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/:pair";//"wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/";
```

and run again I get the following exeption

`2018-10-06 12:07:08.690:WARN:twl.SecureClientSocket:WebSocketClient@1717159510-17: 
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: 404 Not Found
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.onComplete(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.handleContentMessage(HttpParser.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-10-06 12:07:08.696:WARN:twl.SecureClientSocket:main: 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: 404 Not Found
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1895)
    at trading.websocket.luno.SecureClientSocket.main(SecureClientSocket.java:32)
Caused by: 
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: 404 Not Found
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketUpgradeRequest.onComplete(WebSocketUpgradeRequest.java:522)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.ResponseNotifier.notifyComplete(ResponseNotifier.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.terminateResponse(HttpReceiver.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpReceiver.responseSuccess(HttpReceiver.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.messageComplete(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:316)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.handleContentMessage(HttpParser.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseContent(HttpParser.java:1669)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:1517)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.parse(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.process(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpReceiverOverHTTP.receive(HttpReceiverOverHTTP.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpChannelOverHTTP.receive(HttpChannelOverHTTP.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.client.http.HttpConnectionOverHTTP.onFillable(HttpConnectionOverHTTP.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.onFillable(SslConnection.java:422)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$2.succeeded(SslConnection.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Any suggestions would be welcome

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question, I was replacing wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/:pair
with
wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/:XBTZAR. but it should be wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/XBTZAR Just be sure to send your credentials (api_key_id and api_key_secret) in the OnOpen event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the websocket URL I was using is wrong, (`wss://ws.luno.com/api/1/stream/:pair`). I needed to replace *`:pair`* with the currency pair, e.g. *`XBTZAR`*.