# getting SSLHandshakeException when using htmlunit's WebClient with https

Tags: java, ssl, intellij-idea, ssl-certificate

i'm trying to access a web form that's located on an https server and get this exception. i'm using HtmlUnit http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/ and Intellij community with Java 8 on Mac. i've tried to resolve this in several ways:

1. importing the certificate to JVM as described in [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate#) - regarding that i'm not quite sure i've managed to get the certificate itself properly i'm trying to get https://www.misim.gov.il/svinfonadlan2010/ certificate and i took the one under "Certificate Authority Information Access" method #2 (in Chrome)
2. i've checked "accept non-trusted certificates automatically" in Intellij preferences

neither of those worked, and i don't know what to try next