# Download file over HTTPS and SSO in groovy avoiding server certificate validation

Tags: ssl, groovy, https

I want to download a file in groovy over a connection that is both using single sign on (SSO) over HTTPS (SSL) is there an easy way to do this. I'm not intending to build a full blown application so security is not as much of a concern.

```
def data =  new URL("https://server/context/servlet?param1=value1").getText()
print data
```

I currently do the download using curl but would ideally not have to call curl. current used call below.

```
curl --negotiate -u user:pass -L --insecure -o filename.txt  "https://server/context/servlet?param1=value1"
```

[image]

Two key points to the solution i'm looking for 
 - It does not involve making a system call to curl
 - It does not include manually setting up a certificate.

Would consider libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Comment: You could use httpbuilder and set it to ignore SSL issues https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/SSL#ignoresslissues

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the SSL PKIX validation check, in *Groovy*, you can implement a [`X509TrustManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/X509TrustManager.html) in the same way that you do it in *Java*.

Note that this disable the validation server certificate validation, therefore it's a security risk:

```
import javax.net.ssl.*
    
// create a TrustManager to avoid PKIX path validation
def trustManager = [
  checkClientTrusted: { chain, authType ->  },
  checkServerTrusted: { chain, authType ->  },
  getAcceptedIssuers: { null }
] as X509TrustManager

// creat a sslCtx to use "lax" trustManager     
def context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
context.init(null, [trustManager] as TrustManager[], null)
// set as default ssl context   
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory())

// finally you can connect to the server "insecurely"
def data =  new URL("https://server/context/servlet?param1=value1").getText()
print data
```

About your second question, to provide a basic authentication like `curl` does with `--user` argument, you can set a default user/password for your connections using [`Authenticator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html) class:

```
Authenticator.setDefault (new Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication ("user", "pass".toCharArray())
    }
})
```

Note that is possible to do so on other ways in *Groovy* using some libraries, but this is a possible way using standard *Java* classes.