# How to add a SSL self-signed cert to Jenkins for LDAPS within Dockerfile?

Tags: jenkins, docker, dockerfile

I want to enable LDAPS under security in Jenkins but my LDAP server has a self-signed CERT. Has anyone done this or have some pointers on doing this? Do I have to use keytool?

In my Dockerfile I'm trying the following but this won't work:

```
FROM jenkins

USER root

# Install CA certs
COPY ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
RUN chmod +r /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

# Install the Jenkins plugin  
COPY plugins.txt /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt
RUN /usr/local/bin/plugins.sh /usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

# Expose container port 33838 for Jenkins UDP-based auto-discovery
EXPOSE 33848/udp

ENV JAVA_OPTS -Xmx2048m
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It turns out I just need to add this in the Dockerfile where ldap.cer is the cert chain for my self-signed cert.

```
COPY ldap.cer $JAVA_HOME/conf/security
RUN \
    cd $JAVA_HOME/conf/security \
    && keytool -cacerts -storepass changeit -noprompt -trustcacerts -importcert -alias ldapcert -file ldap.cer
```

Comment: I needed to add a "USER root" command before the run to get around some permission problems.

Comment: Oh man, this took me ages before on a full server install. Now it was sooooo easy...... Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, this helped!

Comment: This doesn't work anymore with newer Java versions. However, the fixes are pretty easy: a) `$JAVA_HOME/conf/security` instead of `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security`; b) `-cacerts` instead of `-keystore cacerts` (which actually makes the directory irrelevant). As @MrShark said, you also need to add `USER root` before it, but don't forget to add `USER jenkins` _after_ it - otherwise Jenkins will run as root.

Answer (score 1):

Run keytool to import the CA cert into your java keystore.

See:

[telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 1):

On our build server with *jenkins*, *nexus* and *sonarqube* we use a extracted and prepared `cacerts` file on the host using a start parameter for `docker run`.

See my answer on [Stackoverflow "Importing self-signed cert into Docker's JRE cacert is not recognized by the service"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46770752/2702433)