# PKIX path building failed in docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker

Team - I am trying to connect to elastic 8.2.0 running on my local machine from a spring boot service deployed/running in docker(i.e. Docker Desktop on Windows machine) and getting below issue for SSL

`2022-08-23 01:26:33.811 ERROR [,,] 1 --- [main] c.m.u.s.c.service.ElasticSearchService   : Creation of index failed due to: [PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target]`

please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: maybe its related with this one...[Importing self-signed cert into Docker's JRE cacert is not recognized by the service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41497871/importing-self-signed-cert-into-dockers-jre-cacert-is-not-recognized-by-the-ser)