# facing SSLHandshakeException with OAuth authentication

Tags: java, google-app-engine, sslhandshakeexception

My code:

```
    URL url=new URL(https url with client id and clientsecret);
    HttpURLConnection connect=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connect.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connect.setDoOutput(true);
```

By this i'm getting

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Could not verify SSL certificate
>   for URL:(my url)

And if trying to change to `HttpsURLConnection`:

```
    URL url=new URL(https url with client id and clientsecret);
    HttpsURLConnection connect=(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connect.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connect.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    connect.setDoOutput(true);
```

i'm getting

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection
>   cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

i'm working with GAE. I need to solve this to get the access token.
I didn't got the correct solution by seeing the older questions.

> when m trying through terminal via "curl" i'm able to get the valid access token.

```
curl --data "parameters like client id and client secret and the auth_code" my https url
```

after this m able to get the valid response for token

Comment: even i tried with some piece of code i found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: Is this happening on the development server only or also on a deployed app?

Comment: i hv not yet added this code in deployed app. m just checking in local.

Answer (score 0):

The original issue is caused by an inability to verify the SSL certificate at your domain. This could be because the certificate is bad in some way or because Google isn't aware of the root of the trust chain. You should focus on investigating your SSL set-up.

The second issue was caused by attempting to cast the result of [`javax.net.URL`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)`.openConnection()` (which in the App Engine runtime will return an instance of `com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection`) to `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`, which cannot be done.

Comment: Hi @Nick I tried to get the certificate by executing below code through my terminal then also it  shows like SSL Handshake Error.
**echo -n | openssl s_client -connect <your domain>:443 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ~/<your domain>.crt**

Comment: [Qualys SSL Labs has a great tool to analyze your cert](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/). Worth a try.

Comment: Hi Nick thanx for the url. its really useful.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to load the keystore. You should save the certificate and load the .jks for the connection:

```
package com.tdi.api.brm.service;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.scheme.Scheme;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.tdi.api.brm.servlet.InitServlet;
import com.tdi.api.brm.util.TDI_Constants;
import com.tdi.api.brm.util.TDI_Utility;
import com.tdi.common.exceptions.TDI_CommonException;
import com.tdi.common.utility.TDI_CommonConstants;
import com.tdi.restService.model.tdiapis.ProccessAccountElements;

public class TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl2 extends AbstractBaseService implements TDI_IGProcessAccountService{

static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl2.class);

public TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl2(){
    LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: Contructor: Entered");

    LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: Contructor: Leaving");
}

public ProccessAccountElements processAccount(String payload, String environment) throws Exception{
    LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Entered");

    ProccessAccountElements serviceResp = new ProccessAccountElements();
    String xmlFilePath;
    String xmlString;
    String httpResponsexml;
    String httpPostUri;
    StringEntity stringEntity;
    HttpClient httpClient = null;
    HttpPost httpPost;
    HttpResponse httpResponse;
    HttpEntity httpEntity;

    InputStream keyStoreInputStream;
    String keyStoreFilePath;
    String keyStorePassword;
    KeyStore keyStore;
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory;
    Scheme scheme;

    try{

            xmlFilePath = TDI_Constants.XML_TEMPLATE_DIR.concat(TDI_Constants.FORWARD_SLASH).concat(TDI_Constants.TDI_PROCESS_ACCOUNT_XML);


            xmlString = TDI_Utility.readFromFile(xmlFilePath);

            stringEntity = new StringEntity(payload, HTTP.UTF_8);
            stringEntity.setContentType(TDI_Constants.TEXT_XML);

            httpPostUri = InitServlet.getPropertyValue(environment.concat(TDI_Constants.DELIMITER_UNDERSCORE).concat(TDI_Constants.IG_PROCESS_ACCOUNT_URL1));

            httpPost = new HttpPost(httpPostUri);
            httpPost.setHeader(TDI_Constants.CONTENT_TYPE, TDI_Constants.CONTENT_TYPE_VALUE);
            httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

            keyStorePassword = TDI_Constants.KEY_STORE_PASSWORD;
            keyStoreFilePath = TDI_Constants.BRM_SHARE.concat(TDI_Constants.FORWARD_SLASH).concat(environment).concat(TDI_Constants.DELIMITER_UNDERSCORE).concat(TDI_Constants.PROCESS_ACCOUNT_CERTIFICATE);

            keyStoreInputStream = TDI_Utility.getResourceAsInputStream(keyStoreFilePath);

            keyStore  = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());

            try {
                keyStore.load(keyStoreInputStream, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());
                LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Try: keyStore: Loaded");
            }finally{
                keyStoreInputStream.close();
                LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Try: keyStoreInputStream: Closed");
            }

            socketFactory = new SSLSocketFactory(keyStore);
            socketFactory.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Try: HostnameVerifier: Set");

            scheme = new Scheme(TDI_Constants.HTTPS, socketFactory, TDI_Constants.PORT_443);
            LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Try: Scheme: Created");

            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(scheme);
            LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Try: HttpClient: Registered");

            httpResponse = (BasicHttpResponse) httpClient.execute(httpPost);

            //Capture the TDI-Service un available exception
            if(httpResponse != null &&  httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString().contains(TDI_Constants.WEBSERVICE_UNAVAIALBLE)){
                LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: URL : " + httpPostUri);
                LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: httpResponse.getStatusLine() " + httpResponse.getStatusLine().toString());
                throw new TDI_CommonException(TDI_Constants.WEBSERVICE_ERROR_CODE_404,TDI_Constants.IG_SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE_404);
            }

            if(httpResponse != null) {
                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                httpResponsexml = TDI_Utility.getInputStreamAsString(httpEntity.getContent());
                serviceResp = parseResponseXML (httpEntity, httpResponsexml);       

            }else{
                httpResponsexml = TDI_Constants.COMMON_XML_RESPONSE_ERROR_NO_RESPONSE;
                throw new TDI_CommonException(TDI_CommonConstants.ERROR_CODE_932, httpResponsexml);
            }
            LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Try: Final: HttpResponsexml=[" + httpResponsexml + "]");

        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Try: Leaving");
    }catch(java.net.SocketException soe){
        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: Socket Exception Entered");
        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: Socket Exception: " + soe.getMessage());
        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: Socket Exception Leaving");
        throw new TDI_CommonException(TDI_Constants.WEBSERVICE_ERROR_CODE_404,TDI_Constants.IG_SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE_404);
    }catch(TDI_CommonException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: TDI_CommonException: Entered");
        LOGGER.error("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: TDI_CommonException: " + e);
        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: TDI_CommonException: Leaving");
        serviceResp.setRespCode(TDI_Constants.WDR_WEBSERVICE_ERROR_CODE);
        serviceResp.setRespDesc(TDI_Constants.WDR_SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        throw e;
    }catch(Exception e){
        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: Exception: Entered");
        LOGGER.error("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: Exception: " + e);
        LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Catch: Exception: Leaving");
        serviceResp.setRespCode(TDI_Constants.WDR_WEBSERVICE_ERROR_CODE);
        serviceResp.setRespDesc(TDI_Constants.WDR_SERVICE_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        throw e;
    }

    LOGGER.debug("TDI_IGProcessAccountServiceImpl: processAccount: Leaving");
    return serviceResp;
}
```

}

Check the scheme here in this sample.

Comment: hi JRadcliffe thanx for the link but i've already checked that and i didnt got the desired solution.

Comment: Updated to see if that could help with the scheme. Maybe that was missing if you can use the DefaultHttpClient