# ValidatorException HTTPClient Java

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-commons-httpclient

I am receiving the following error. I will post what I am doing code wise and then will post the stack trace to which I have struggled to find adequate information to fix. I am using a self signed certificate.

```
SSLContext sslContext = null;

        try {

            sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
                    //.loadTrustMaterial(new File("~local_trust_store"), //"pass".toCharArray())
                    .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {

                        @Override
                        public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType)
                                throws CertificateException {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                sslContext, NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);

        // create a default client
        httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(poolConnectionManager)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
                //.setDefaultRequestConfig(config).build();
```

EXCEPTION RESPONSE:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:380)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
        at com.socievo.nightli.sparktestapp.AppService.sendTestRequest(AppService.java:205)
        at com.socievo.nightli.sparktestapp.AppController.lambda$new$1(AppController.java:37)
        at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)
        at spark.webserver.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:162)
        at spark.webserver.JettyHandler.doHandle(JettyHandler.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:189)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection.onFillable(SslConnection.java:192)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:245)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:75)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
        ... 42 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
        ... 48 more
```

I am not sure what is causing this issue. I am posting like so

```
    // running test server with self signed cert stored in trust store above (note I have also used the jks in place of trust store above)
    String URL = "https://localhost:1000"

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

    postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    postRequest.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    StringEntity postingJson = new StringEntity("{\"id\":\"12345\"}", "UTF8");

    postRequest.setEntity(postingJson);

    httpResponse = httpClient.execute(postRequest);

    if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {

        throw exception;
    }
```

I have tried a numerous amount of things to get this to work. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: As to the linked question, as you can see this is different, with the code I provided which should be bypassing any issues, with the trust strategy that I have provided code for, yet I am still getting the error.

Comment: You're using a self-signed SSL certificate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Comment: I had tried these solutions, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it ended up being related to the fact that I was using a `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` which isn't shown in the question, although it is in the stacktrace funny enough. It took a lot of digging. But anyone else, who has a similar setup, it's probably some other configuration setting that is causing the problem, for me it was the lack of configured `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager` Hope this helps anyone in the future.