# Aerogear SSLHandshakeException CertPathValidatorException

Tags: android, push-notification, ssl-certificate, aerogear

I have just started tested [the aerogear push notifcation solution](https://aerogear.org/docs/unifiedpush/). I installed it locally via docker. It seems that there're issues with the SSL certificate. 
I even found [this ticket](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AGDROID-270?workflowName=GIT%20Pull%20Request%20workflow%20&stepId=6) which seems to be closed.
I tried to register an android Emulator and I am getting the following issue:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.addBodyRequest(HttpRestProvider.java:219)
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.post(HttpRestProvider.java:147)
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.post(HttpRestProvider.java:134)
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.unifiedpush.fcm.AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar$4.doInBackground(AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar.java:180)
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.unifiedpush.fcm.AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar$4.doInBackground(AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar.java:135)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103) 
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) 
at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.addBodyRequest(HttpRestProvider.java:219) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.post(HttpRestProvider.java:147) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.post(HttpRestProvider.java:134) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.unifiedpush.fcm.AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar$4.doInBackground(AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar.java:180) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.unifiedpush.fcm.AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar$4.doInBackground(AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar.java:135) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:318) 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:219) 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115) 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556) 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method) 
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103) 
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143) 
at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185) 
at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:341) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.addBodyRequest(HttpRestProvider.java:219) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.post(HttpRestProvider.java:147) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.pipe.http.HttpRestProvider.post(HttpRestProvider.java:134) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.unifiedpush.fcm.AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar$4.doInBackground(AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar.java:180) 
at org.jboss.aerogear.android.unifiedpush.fcm.AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar$4.doInBackground(AeroGearFCMPushRegistrar.java:135) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly inside of Docker is using a self signed certificate to encrypt HTTP traffic between Android and UPS.  There are several ways to work around this.

1. Sign your certificate using a certificate authority
2. Expose port 8080 in your Docker image and connect using that
3. Use certificate pinning in Android N and load the SSL certificate that Wildfly is using into your app (https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CertificatePinning)
4. Inject a TrustManager that ignores SSL errors ([telling java to accept self-signed ssl certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/telling-java-to-accept-self-signed-ssl-certificate))

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have seen such workarounds (the ticket that I spoke about in the link in the question is also proposing quiet the same). I was wondering if I could get a real solution (without ignoring SSL errors...).

Comment: The real solutions are to use a certificate signed by LetsEncrypt (or any other authority), use certificate pinning, use a proxy, or don't use https.