# Not getting correct HTTP Response Code in Selenium WebDriver with java

Tags: java, url, httpurlconnection

I am trying to do automation of find all the broken link of a page. I have gone through so many articles here but none helped. The real problem I am facing is I am not able to get(returing) the correct httpresponse code. Below is the code:

```
public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        return connection.getResponseCode();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: what is the OUTPUT (HTTP response code) you observed? what you expected & what have you observed? pls share the details.

Comment: I am getting -1 only even for the valid links. For valid links I expect 2XX.

Comment: In **catch block**, print the exception as `return connection.getResponseCode();` is NOT getting executed, I suspect there are exceptions thrown. Share the stack trace with us.

Comment: give us one `urlString` as an example which is giving `-1` for valid url. we will try it out. what is the IDE you are using?

Comment: thanks Naveen. I am using eclipse. below is the stacktrace

-1https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/about.html?fg=1
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: why is it tagged with selenium?

Comment: @metar i just removed the selenium tags for the OP

Answer (score 0):

you cant get the response using this code alone using java.
you need the java selenium driver code for this to be implemented.

use the below code to get the right response:

```
private static int statusCode;
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException{
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
    for(int i = 0; i < links.size(); i++){
        if(!(links.get(i).getAttribute("href") == null) && !(links.get(i).getAttribute("href").equals(""))){
            if(links.get(i).getAttribute("href").contains("http")){
                statusCode= intgetResponseCode(links.get(i).getAttribute("href").trim());
                if(statusCode == 403){
                    System.out.println("HTTP 403 Forbidden # " + i + " " + links.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
                }
            }
        }   
    }   
}


public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    huc.connect();
    return huc.getResponseCode();
    }
```

Else you can do get the response by setting the response method as "HEAD" [if its a simple test].

hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: Please provide the code of intgetResponseCode(url) function. Main problem is the function is not returning correct response code. What ever you provided is before and after getting the response code.

Comment: Its the same code that you're using. The code you've used is just fine. Try and lemme know

Comment: I tired but statusCode is always getting -1 from getResponseCode(), even for valid links

Comment: The return statement in the final line is the issue. Updated my answer. Pls check

Comment: That code is already provided in other thread and its not working. I am getting below error

unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: ok its working for me, by specifying the firefox location in the  
-- WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(<<path>>); line

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me with given example URL:

```
public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) throws IOException {
//      String url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=mkyong";

        String url  = "https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/about.html?fg=1";

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        // optional default is GET
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");

        //add request header
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.connect();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

}
```

Output I got:

```
Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/about.html?fg=1
Response Code : 200
```

Comment: The output you got is the exact I am expecting but I am getting error

 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: add the ssl certificate to the java certificate store and the error should be gone.. or auto accept any certificate :O

Comment: @metar: I am trying to do the same thing. Could you please explain me the process/steps.

Comment: How come you got both the response code & exception? If you are getting `200` code, then that means there is NO exception is thrown. Anyways. add `throws IOException` to the method and try.,

Comment: @Naveen: I am expecting(wanted) the same output as you are getting but I am getting error sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: I have NOT added any certificate. did you try by throwing the exception?

Comment: @VikasRathore, see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2893932/1545397)