# WildFly 11 - Use certificate to make https requests

Tags: java, certificate, wildfly, jsse, wildfly-11

I'm a bit lost of how I can use certificate in WidlFly 11. I re the doccumentation and found a lot of terms like JSSE, OpenSSL, Elytron, ApplicationRealm.
The problem occurs when I execute the code

```
final URL url = new URL("https://someUrl");
HttpsURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
```

This exception is thrown `sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

So, what exactly need to configure? I tried the section "Enable One-way SSL/TLS for Applications" in [Elytron Doccumentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY/WildFly+Elytron+Security#WildFlyElytronSecurity-EnableOnewaySSL%2FTLSforApplications.) but didn't works.

ps: I'm using java 9.01
ps2: I'm using standalone-full.xml

let me know if you need more informations

Answer (score 5):

This is unrelated to WildFly - you need to configure certificates trusted by java URL connections - you need to create and configure truststore:

1. create keystore containing certificate of server (if it is self-signed certificate), or better, certificate of its CA:

   ```
   keytool -import -file myCA.cert -alias myCA -storepass mypassword -noprompt -keystore my.truststore
   ```
2. start using created keystore file as truststore in WildFly by setting `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword` system properties:

   ```
   bin/jboss-cli.sh -c
   /system-property=javax.net.ssl.trustStore:add(value="/path/to/my.truststore")
   /system-property=javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword:add(value="mypassword")
   ```

Elytron documentation you mention is related only to server side - but this is client side configuration, which is not currently handled by it.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate is not trusted, iirc there is a self-signed certificate in WildFly 11 so yo need to trust it or install a real certificate.
[Accept server's self-signed ssl certificate in Java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/accept-servers-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-java-client)