# How to reset the system property javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword?

Tags: java, ssl, wildfly, truststore

Some time ago I had a wildfly server with a custom truststore for SSL Certificates. I created it with the help of this answer on stackoverflow:

[WildFly 11 - Use certificate to make https requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48521776/wildfly-11-use-certificate-to-make-https-requests)

It worked and was all fine.
Now the old wildfly server doesnt exist anymore and I have a new one on the same machine.
I wanted to do the same thing for this wildfly server but get an error now when trying:

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "WFLYCTL0212: Duplicate resource [(\"system-property\" => \"javax.net.ssl.trustStore\")]",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Why? You don't need to supply that password at all. The system will still work,.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a couple options. You can either remove it and add it back or you can overwrite it.

To remove it:

```
/system-property=javax.net.ssl.trustStore:remove
```

To overwrite it:

```
/system-property=javax.net.ssl.trustStore:write-attribute(name=value, value="your_new_value")
```

That said you may want to look at the [security documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/24/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html) on how to setup a truststore.