# How to fix javax.net.ssl.SSLHandShakeException accessing JIRA

Tags: java, credentials, sslhandshakeexception, httpsurlconnection

I want to match issues in JIRA with other datasource.
I can use curl:

> curl -u myname:mypassword
>   https://jira.myorganization.com/rest/api/latest/issue/TR-1234

This will return info about the issue, for exampel TR-1234, that I want to check some data for.

In java I want to do the same thing but I get javax.net.ssl.SSLHandShakeException

The program I try to run:

```
    import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {


            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL("https://jira.myorganization.com/rest/api/latest/issue/TR-1234");

            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

String userpass = "myusername:mypassword";
        String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(userpass.getBytes()));
        con.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", basicAuth);
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            System.out.println("Resp="+ con.getResponseCode()+" "+con.getResponseMessage());

            String contentType = con.getHeaderField("Content-Type");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (con.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            con.disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

Can I somehow pass userid and password to the URL. The application is a tool and it would be ok to let the user input his name and password.

Comment: I tried to add some basicAuth but gives the same fault.

Comment: If you use self-signed sertificate answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893932/6473877

Comment: @sintasy That solution works.