# unable to find valid certification path to requested target - Keycloak - Springboot - self-signed certificate - Tests

Tags: spring-boot, ssl, junit, keycloak

I have integration tests in my spring boot application and some tests need to get a token from Keycloak. Every communication is via SSL with a self-signed certificate.

When launching those tests I got that exception :

```
SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

The problem seem similar to [Accept server's self-signed ssl certificate in Java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/accept-servers-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-java-client) but this solution doesn't work for me.

This is where I get the token :

```
private AccessTokenResponse getToken() throws GeneralSecurityException {        
        Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(keycloakAuthServerUrl, keycloakRealm, 
            login, password, keycloakResource, keycloakCredentialsSecret);
        return keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried setting up keystore for keycloak https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/index.html#enabling-ssl-https-for-the-keycloak-server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [Accept server's self-signed ssl certificate in Java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/accept-servers-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-java-client) , create a custom trust manager :

```
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

public class TestTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        @Override
        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[0];
        }
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
        }
}
```

Then add it in the keycloak "constructor" :

```
private AccessTokenResponse getToken() throws GeneralSecurityException {
        // Install the all-trusting trust manager
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new TestTrustManager() }, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        Keycloak keycloak = Keycloak.getInstance(keycloakAuthServerUrl, keycloakRealm, 
            login, password, keycloakResource, keycloakCredentialsSecret, sslContext); // <--- !!! ADD IT HERE !!!
        return keycloak.tokenManager().getAccessToken();
    }
```

Comment: I have only these keycloak properties: serverUr; realm; grantType; clientId; clientSecret...How can i modify the method getToken()? please help me...I need to trust ssl certificate