# SmackException NoResponseException When Logging into XMPP OpenFire Server from JMeter

Tags: jmeter, xmpp, openfire

I am trying to log into a local OpenFire XMPP server through JMeter. I've followed tutorials and have my XMPP Samplers inside JMeter. The Connect one is fine. The log in one gives me an error of SmackException$NoResponseException: null.

I'm thinking it has something to do with certificates or some sort, which is why it's unable to log in. When I use a GUI client like Pidgin to log in, I have to accept certificates (which are the default ones, so self-signed I'm guessing) but this is timing out and giving me that response. How can I bypass this?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [XMPP Plugin source code](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/xmpp/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/xmpp/JMeterXMPPConnectionBase.java#L141) it appears that it should accept all the certificates no matter of their validity [just like JMeter does for HTTP Request samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#opt_ssl) so the issue must be somewhere else

Try [increasing logging verbosity for the XMPP plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
<Logger name="com.blazemeter.jmeter.xmpp" level="debug" />
```

and on JMeter restart you should see way more information regarding what's going on in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

Going forward be aware that it's possible to [import self-signed certificates into JVM truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2893932/2897748) and point JMeter to the truststore by `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` property