# Secure Sockets in Java without CA

Tags: java, security, ssl

I am working on a small android app, only for test purposes. I can get a secure connection with JSSE, but can i keep the server public certificate on the client side.
Without registering on a CA.

Comment: For this to be secure you need to encode the specific certificate you want to accept into your client application. If you blindly trust any self-signed certificate, then anyone can spoof the server (or proxy the requests).

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. This is what i wanted to do, but i have not found how to implement this into JSSE.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I want to make a secure connection to my backend server, but instead of veryfing the server certificate over a CA, i want to store it client sided.

Comment: Just import the server certificate into your truststore.

Comment: Thank you, if did that and it worked, i used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/accept-servers-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-java-client