# Call https endpoints in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache, https

How to call https endpoint with httpclient5. I cant use this way

```
SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
```

Comment: You don't have to do anything if the certificate is not self-signed. If it's self-signed you have to import it in the trusttore

Comment: how to import @SimonMartinelli

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accept server's self-signed ssl certificate in Java client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893819/accept-servers-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-java-client)