# Java Keystore reload whilst in runtime

Tags: java, ssl, keystore

I have searched around for this one, but there wasn't really a clear answer. I have created a keystore on my system. As my application runs It accepts self-signed certificates and adds them to the keystore without problem. However, the whole applicaiton has to be restarted in order for the changes to take effect.

How can I get java to reload the keystore?

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "keystore");
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out the key store manager. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection