# facing class cast error with setSSLSocketFactory between two packages

Tags: java, ssl, https

I have created my own SSLSocketFactory as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

```
private SSLSocketFactory newSslSocketFactory() {
    try {
        // Get an instance of the Bouncy Castle KeyStore format
        KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
        // Get theraw resource, which contains the keystore with
        // your trusted certificates (root and any intermediate certs)
        Context context = this.activity;
        Resources _resources = context.getResources();
        InputStream in = _resources.openRawResource(R.raw.mystore);
        try {
            // Initialize the keystore with the provided trusted certificates
            // Also provide the password of the keystore
            trusted.load(in, "mypassword".toCharArray());
        } finally {
            in.close();
        }
        // Pass the keystore to the SSLSocketFactory. The factory is responsible
        // for the verification of the server certificate.
        SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(trusted);
        // Hostname verification from certificate

        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.STRICT_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
        return sf;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

Actually i need to set this `SSLSocketFactory` on the `HttpsURLConnection` before connecting. But when i try to set it on `HttpsURLConnection` by calling

```
(HttpsURLConnection )connection.setSSLSocketFactory(trusted);
```

At this point am facing cast class error between 2 packages `org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory` and `javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`.

How to solve this?

Comment: Please post the full stacktrace of the exception.

Answer (score 0):

Am not getting any exception with the above piece of code.

But the problem is that, when am trying to set the `SSLSocketFactory` on the `HttpsURLConnection` using:

```
(HttpsURLConnection )connection.setSSLSocketFactory(trusted)
```

It is showing "*The method `setSSLSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory)` in the type `HttpsURLConnection` is not applicable for the arguments`(SSLSocketFactory)`*".

Because the method `setSSLSocketFactory` is there in both the packages.