# Using Demo Certificates

Tags: java, certificate

I have few demo certificates containing: csr files along with public and private keys of both the parties' security certificates.

How should I use them in my java program?

The demo certificates are required for client server communication. The client is a standalone java program and the server is a servlet deployed on jboss. How do I use these certificates. The keytool command creates a new public-private key pair. How tdo I add the existing certificates which are already signed by a demo ca. to both the client and the server.

Comment: agreeing with the first comment - however there is a useful discussion on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection

Comment: @Linus kleen: I have a java program as the client and a servlet deployed in jboss as the server. I want to use the certificate to encrypt data and send between the client and server.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how you want to send the data? Showing some code is always a good start.