# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, push-notification, liferay

I'm trying to send push notifications to my device using **javapns** library in **liferay**. Here's the code:

```
private void pushNotification(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) {

        try {
            System.out.println("Push");

            Push.alert("Hello World!", "ck.p12", "PASSPHRASE", false, "TOKEN");

        } catch (CommunicationException e) {
            System.out.println("CommunicationException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeystoreException e) {
            System.out.println("KeystoreException");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I'm getting this error when the pushNotification is called:

```
ERROR [PushNotificationManager:450] Delivery error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I've googled it but couldn't find any solution.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` exception is usually thrown when the server you're trying to connect to does not have a valid certificate from an authorized CA.

Put simply, the server you're attempting to connect to is most likely using a self-signed certificate and you have to accomodate for that in your Java code. This involves creating a custom `KeyStore`, etc. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/1101070) Stack Overflow answer for full implementation details.

Comment: Yeah I faced same problem. You need to provide keystore and keystore password to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Set the following properties on the server

```
javax.net.ssl.keyStore=../keystore/keystoreFile.jks
javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=yourPassword
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=../keystore/keystoreFile.jks
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=yourPassword
javax.net.debug=true
```

you can create your keystore using

```
keytool -genkey -alias myKeyStore -keyalg RSA -keystore /home/aniket/keystore/keystoreFile.jks
```

Answer (score 0):

This algo happens when for example the server **only accept TLS** and your client is trying to create a SSL connection... check also the server/client side config