# InaccessibleWSDLException with handshake_failure alert despite setting keystore and truststore

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, soap

I'm developing a Springboot application that will communicate with a server having SOAP Web service. Mutual authentication or 2-Way SSL authentication is used for the communication. I have looked the suggestions given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068210/sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208244/sslhandshakeexception-received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-after-java-6-8) and have set the following: -

In **application.properties**

```
server.ssl.key-alias=testclient
server.ssl.key-password=password
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:testclientselfsigned
server.ssl.key-store-password=password
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.trust-store=classpath:myTruststore
server.ssl.trust-store-type=JKS
server.ssl.trust-store-password=password
```

In my **code calling the web service**

```
    static {

            URL urlTruststore = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myTruststore");
            URL urlKeystore = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("testclientselfsigned");
            if (urlTruststore != null) {
                logger.info("URL TRUST STORE:\t" + urlTruststore.getFile());
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", urlTruststore.getFile());
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword","password");
            }

            if (urlKeystore != null) {
                logger.info("URL KEY STORE:\t" + urlKeystore.getFile());
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore",urlKeystore.getFile());
                System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","password");
            }

String WS_URL = "https://uatexample.testserv.com/uat/ssl/custService";
                URL url = new URL(WS_URL);
                QName qname = new QName("http://www.sampleserv.com/services", "custService");
                Service service = Service.create(url, qname);
                CustService client = service.getPort(CustService.class);
```

It is at this point `CustService client = service.getPort(CustService.class);` that I'm getting the following exception

```
com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.InaccessibleWSDLException: 2 counts of InaccessibleWSDLException.

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

Please note that **myTruststore.jks** contains the certificate sent to me by the server** and **testclientselfsigned.jks** contains the client certificate.

I have tried all the suggestions I found here to add a Keystore and Truststore in my code, but nothing worked. However, I have tried the same in Soap-UI and it worked.

Comment: you can see many useful info with ssllabs.com It shows server cipersuites and supported protocols, and also validate certificate chain and name. It your case server is wrongly configured, and has certificate for `cc.sedoparking.com` instead of `uatexample.testserv.com` You should disable certificate name validation if you want tot connect to this server.

Comment: can you add the debug option (-Djavax.net.debug=ssl,handshake) as recommended on the link you sent and post the output?

Comment: you can use -Djavax.net.debug=all too http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html

Comment: @Carlos Could you please tell me where to add the debug option? I'm quite new to this and have no idea where to plug that in. Is it in my code?

Comment: @Auro you can pass it as an argument in your app startup or if not set it, have you tried `System.setProperty("javax.net.debug”,”all”);` ?