# notnoop java-apns throw javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, spring, security, ssl, jetty

## Detail

I using  [notnoop java-apns](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns)  push mdm message,**I try in     main function push message is ok!** but add into spring mvm  run in jetty/tomcat web context throws javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure ! help me.

### using spring mvc method

```
ModelAttribute
RequestMapping("/deviceinfo")
public String pushCommand(HttpServletRequest request)
{
  String id = request.getParameter("id");
  Device device = deviceManager.get(new Long(id));
  log.debug(device);
  log.debug(device.getToken());
  ApnsService service = APNS.newService().withCert( ClassLoader
  .getSystemResourceAsStream("mdm_push.p12"),"123456")
  .withProductionDestination().build();
  String mdmPayload = APNS.newPayload().mdm(device.getToken().getPushMagic()).build();
  service.push(device.getToken().getToken(), mdmPayload);
  log.warn("mdmDeviceInfoCommand");
  return "device form";
}
```

### error message:

```
INFO [Thread-19] ApnsConnectionImpl.run(170) | Exception while waiting for error code
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at >com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:114)
DEBUG [qtp297885139-65] ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(218) | Made a new connection to APNS
INFO [Thread-20] ApnsConnectionImpl.run(170) | Exception while waiting for error code
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at >com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:114)
INFO [qtp297885139-65] ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(264) | Failed to send message >Message(Id=1; Token=07BE34F5A71A; Payload={"mdm":"E101CB39-697A-4883-B303-67713DEE836E"})... >trying again after delay
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1959)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1077)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:882)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at >com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl$1MonitoringThread.run(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:114)
```

Comment: Try running Java with -`Djavax.net.debug=ssl`

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion from [@artbristol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/116509/artbristol) will show you what the root cause is.

```
-Djavax.net.debug=ssl
```

Some examples:

- [bad/missing ciphers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15560272/775715)
- [bad/missing keystore information](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9504457/775715)