# APNS Handshake Failure from Scala

Tags: scala, ssl, apple-push-notifications, javapns

I'm trying to send a push notification to apple device (iphone) using Scala, and [Notnoop APNS](https://github.com/notnoop/java-apns), but when i ran this code:

```
import com.notnoop.apns._
val service = APNS.newService().withCert("certfile.p12", "passphrase").withAppleDestination(true).build()

service.start()

val payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody("nomnomnom").sound("default")

service.push("deviceToken", payload.build())

service.stop()
```

i always stuck on this, ssl handshake error:

```
Thread-20, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498260/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure), i may have invalid certificate, but I'm sure this certificate works, because using [this PHP sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17441504/how-to-connect-server-with-ssl-in-ios-using-certification), i can send a push notification correctly.

Any idea where's my process gone wrong?