# Received fatal alert: handshake_failure from Java but not from browser

Tags: java, ssl, soap, wsdl, sslhandshakeexception

I have gone through most of the links in stack overflow regarding this post but I just does not seem to have a clear understanding of this concept. Please note that I am new to this topic and I am still in exploring phase,

Here is my problem (I doubt it may be duplicate)

My Program is giving this error,

```
IO exception: Service is not available at the specified location: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure.
```

**Note :** There is a log which says "Certificate is valid". So In anyways the certificate problem is not there but I understand from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498260/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure) that it might be the case that the server has the certificate which was not issued by CA. But my question is I am able to access the WSDL from the browser. But when I give the same keystore path to my Java it is unable to hit the server there by giving this error!!!

*So here is my doubt:*

When my browser is able to load the WSDL why can't my Java able to access? Is it that browser has some other certificates which my java is unable to look up? What all certificate path my java is expecting?

I tried to load the wsdl into SOAP UI with SSL settings enabled but no luck it says

[image]

Any type of inputs or guidance or references are appreciated.

Comment: Did you go through [**this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353849/received-fatal-alert-handshake-failure-through-sslhandshakeexception/6353956#6353956) ??

Comment: Yes my qnt is why is it working in the browser? when it is problem with SSL vs TSL ?