# Java SSL communication

Tags: java, security, ssl, certificate

I am trying to make SSL communication between client/server.

So far I have created `java.security.cert.X509Certificate` from a **keystore**. What should I do next in order to make this communication successful. Any example will be helpful.

Comment: What comunication do you use? Some framework or App Servers (Tomcat) are used?

Comment: Client server communication. on my side its spring, IBM Websphere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer solves my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/420613
Also see this [code](http://www.imrantariq.com/blog/?p=867).

Comment: You don't need any of that to solve this problem. You can accomplish all that via the system properties mentioned in the document I cited.

Comment: I don't want to use system properties. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: The answer you cited is another way, and it doesn't use system properties. How many ways do you need exactly?

Comment: @EJP I only need this way that I cited please.

Comment: So therefore you don't need to ask for another way. So, don't ask for another way.

Comment: This way use HttpsURLConnection for communication. But to send and Soap response I am using SOAPConnection. HttpsURLConnection can set conn.setSSLSocketFactory(sslFactory); but SOAPConnection cannot.

Comment: @EJP: Did you look into it? How to set sslFactory in SOAPConnection? http://stackoverflow.com/q/10897881/420613

Answer (score 2):

> So far I have created java.security.cert.X509Certificate

You don't need that.

Follow all the instructions in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html).

Comment: But one of my senior told that I will use this certificate for communication. Also I am not finding any help from your link. Can you please point to one example?

Comment: @imran You need a private key and a *certificate.* What you don't need is a `java.security.cert.X509Certificate`: that's an object in a running Java program, produced by loading from a certificate file or a keystore. JSSE does all that for you. I can't imagine why you didn't find the official reference guide helpful, and the code examples that it provides.

Comment: Yes. As I was unaware of what I should do. If you mention this early then it was good as I spent a lot of time on coming to a point.

Comment: @imrantariq I cannot see the point of this comment. You seem to be just shooting the messenger and blaming me for your own time management issues.