# Axis 2 webservice SSL communication

Tags: java, web-services, security, apache-axis, ssl-certificate

I am getting **Soap Response** from this code

```
SOAPConnectionFactory sfc = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = sfc.createConnection();
SOAPMessage soapMessageResponse = connection.call(soapRequest, new URL(serviceLocation));
```

How can I make it SSL based?

I know how to create `SSLSocketFactory` from `SSLContext` giving my specified **keystore**.

How can I tell `SOAPConnection` class about `SSLSocketFactory` or `SSLContext`? So that my communication can be secured.

I do not want to set keystore in system property or xml file. I am using Websphere 7.

### EDIT:

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl.callJAXWSDispatch(SOAPConnectionImpl.java:416)
    ... 49 more
Caused by: javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
    at com.ibm.ws.webservices.engine.xmlsoap.saaj13only.SOAPConnectionJAXWS.call(SOAPConnectionJAXWS.java:72)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General SSLEngine problem
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code will not work in case of SSL.

```
SOAPMessage soapMessageResponse = connection.call(soapRequest, new URL(serviceLocation));
```

In order to get response through SSL from axis2 webservice you need to open streams like given `[here][1]`.

Answer (score 2):

Log in to Admin console and add the certificate via SSL certificate and key management > SSL configurations > NodeDefaultSSLSettings > Key stores and certificates > NodeDefaultTrustStore > Signer certificates

Answer (score 1):

Typically you dont need to do anything apart from giving your endpoint URL that starts with https://.

Axis2 uses http-commons which in turn will use JSSE takes care of the security. So as long as you have configured your JSSE correctly it should work out of the box with no changes except passing the https in URL.

Comment: According to my JSSE understanding. It helps in building trust from given keystore. I am using 'connection.call(soapRequest, new URL(serviceLocation));' How can this call know that Trust has been established. When I give https url it throws exception

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: Wow - "General SSLEngine problem" - that tells us absolutely nothing. Ok, try setting -Djavax.net.debug=all - it might give more debug information that might help to identify the issue.

Comment: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Certificate chaining error".

Comment: Try this - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14253079

Answer (score 0):

Imran, did you try this tip? "you have to retrieve the signer certificates from the remote host you are trying to connect and adding them to the WAS server trust store"

http://turanunes.wordpress.com/2011/05/04/cwpki0022e-ssl-handshake-failure/

Comment: Thanks but how can I add certificate to them to the WAS server trust store through Java code?