# HTTP Request to Wikipedia gives no result

Tags: java, html, http

I try to fetch HTML per Code. When fetching from "http://www.google.com" for example it works perfect. When trying to fetch from "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php" I do not get any results.

Does someone have any idea ?

Code:

```
    String sURL="http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Countries&prop=info&gcmlimit=500&format=json";

    String sText=readfromURL(sURL);



public static String readfromURL(String sURL){

    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL(sURL);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    URLConnection urlconnect = null;
    try {
        urlconnect = url.openConnection();

        urlconnect.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlconnect.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String inputLine;
    String sEntireContent="";
    try {
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        sEntireContent=sEntireContent+inputLine;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sEntireContent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the request limit. Try to check the response code.

From the documentation (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette):

> If you make your requests in series rather than in parallel (i.e. wait
>   for the one request to finish before sending a new request, such that
>   you're never making more than one request at the same time), then you
>   should definitely be fine.

Be sure that you do not do few request at a time

**Update**

I did verification on my local your code - you are correct it does not work. Fix - you need to use https, so it would work:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=categorymembers&gcmtitle=Category:Countries&prop=info&gcmlimit=500&format=json
```

result:

```
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"5165":{"pageid":5165,"ns":0,"title":"Country","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T20:09:05Z","lastrevid":686706429,"length":12695},"5112305":{"pageid":5112305,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by continent","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-18T17:31:54Z","lastrevid":681415612,"length":133},"14353213":{"pageid":14353213,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by form of government","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-08-13T23:33:29Z","lastrevid":675984011,"length":261},"5112467":{"pageid":5112467,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by international organization","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-18T05:11:12Z","lastrevid":686245148,"length":123},"4696391":{"pageid":4696391,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by language","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T01:17:18Z","lastrevid":675966601,"length":333},"5112374":{"pageid":5112374,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by status","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-08-13T21:05:47Z","lastrevid":675966630,"length":30},"708617":{"pageid":708617,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Lists of countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-18T05:08:45Z","lastrevid":681553760,"length":256},"46624537":{"pageid":46624537,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Caspian littoral states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-23T08:40:34Z","lastrevid":663549987,"length":50},"18066512":{"pageid":18066512,"ns":14,"title":"Category:City-states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-29T20:14:14Z","lastrevid":679367764,"length":145},"2019528":{"pageid":2019528,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Country classifications","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-25T09:09:13Z","lastrevid":675966465,"length":182},"935240":{"pageid":935240,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Country codes","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T06:05:53Z","lastrevid":546489724,"length":222},"36819536":{"pageid":36819536,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries in fiction","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-03T06:09:16Z","lastrevid":674147667,"length":169},"699787":{"pageid":699787,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Fictional countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T18:43:25Z","lastrevid":610289877,"length":356},"804303":{"pageid":804303,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Former countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-21T09:58:52Z","lastrevid":668632882,"length":403},"7213567":{"pageid":7213567,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Island countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-22T22:10:37Z","lastrevid":648502876,"length":157},"3046541":{"pageid":3046541,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Landlocked countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-04T00:45:24Z","lastrevid":648502892,"length":54},"743058":{"pageid":743058,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Middle Eastern countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-12T14:41:59Z","lastrevid":677900732,"length":495},"41711462":{"pageid":41711462,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Mongol states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-23T07:36:21Z","lastrevid":687093637,"length":121},"30645082":{"pageid":30645082,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Country names","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-03-07T06:33:19Z","lastrevid":561256656,"length":94},"21218559":{"pageid":21218559,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Outlines of countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-07T18:04:29Z","lastrevid":645312408,"length":248},"37943702":{"pageid":37943702,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Proposed countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T02:30:25Z","lastrevid":668630396,"length":130},"15086044":{"pageid":15086044,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Turkic states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T06:23:35Z","lastrevid":677424552,"length":114},"32809189":{"pageid":32809189,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Works about countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T08:45:32Z","lastrevid":620016516,"length":153},"27539189":{"pageid":27539189,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Wikipedia books on countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-04-11T05:12:25Z","lastrevid":546775798,"length":203},"35317198":{"pageid":35317198,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Wikipedia categories named after countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T18:35:14Z","lastrevid":641689352,"length":202}}}}
{"batchcomplete":"","query":{"pages":{"5165":{"pageid":5165,"ns":0,"title":"Country","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T20:09:05Z","lastrevid":686706429,"length":12695},"5112305":{"pageid":5112305,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by continent","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-18T17:31:54Z","lastrevid":681415612,"length":133},"14353213":{"pageid":14353213,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by form of government","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-08-13T23:33:29Z","lastrevid":675984011,"length":261},"5112467":{"pageid":5112467,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by international organization","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-18T05:11:12Z","lastrevid":686245148,"length":123},"4696391":{"pageid":4696391,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by language","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T01:17:18Z","lastrevid":675966601,"length":333},"5112374":{"pageid":5112374,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries by status","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-08-13T21:05:47Z","lastrevid":675966630,"length":30},"708617":{"pageid":708617,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Lists of countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-18T05:08:45Z","lastrevid":681553760,"length":256},"46624537":{"pageid":46624537,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Caspian littoral states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-23T08:40:34Z","lastrevid":663549987,"length":50},"18066512":{"pageid":18066512,"ns":14,"title":"Category:City-states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-29T20:14:14Z","lastrevid":679367764,"length":145},"2019528":{"pageid":2019528,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Country classifications","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-25T09:09:13Z","lastrevid":675966465,"length":182},"935240":{"pageid":935240,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Country codes","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T06:05:53Z","lastrevid":546489724,"length":222},"36819536":{"pageid":36819536,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Countries in fiction","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-03T06:09:16Z","lastrevid":674147667,"length":169},"699787":{"pageid":699787,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Fictional countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T18:43:25Z","lastrevid":610289877,"length":356},"804303":{"pageid":804303,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Former countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-09-21T09:58:52Z","lastrevid":668632882,"length":403},"7213567":{"pageid":7213567,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Island countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-22T22:10:37Z","lastrevid":648502876,"length":157},"3046541":{"pageid":3046541,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Landlocked countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-04T00:45:24Z","lastrevid":648502892,"length":54},"743058":{"pageid":743058,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Middle Eastern countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-12T14:41:59Z","lastrevid":677900732,"length":495},"41711462":{"pageid":41711462,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Mongol states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-23T07:36:21Z","lastrevid":687093637,"length":121},"30645082":{"pageid":30645082,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Country names","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-03-07T06:33:19Z","lastrevid":561256656,"length":94},"21218559":{"pageid":21218559,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Outlines of countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-07T18:04:29Z","lastrevid":645312408,"length":248},"37943702":{"pageid":37943702,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Proposed countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T02:30:25Z","lastrevid":668630396,"length":130},"15086044":{"pageid":15086044,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Turkic states","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-20T06:23:35Z","lastrevid":677424552,"length":114},"32809189":{"pageid":32809189,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Works about countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T08:45:32Z","lastrevid":620016516,"length":153},"27539189":{"pageid":27539189,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Wikipedia books on countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-04-11T05:12:25Z","lastrevid":546775798,"length":203},"35317198":{"pageid":35317198,"ns":14,"title":"Category:Wikipedia categories named after countries","contentmodel":"wikitext","pagelanguage":"en","touched":"2015-10-17T18:35:14Z","lastrevid":641689352,"length":202}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you can see from the code, this is a onetime request.

Comment: form this code - yes, but I was not sure that you did not run this code in threads, or even you have 3 programs with this code  that runs in the same time on your PC. Maybe you forgot to switch one and run other. So I just mark that you need to be sure it's not because you reach limit

Comment: look at my update please - you need to use https, it redirects from http to https so you receive zero in the first response. You need to follow redirect or use https

Comment: It works ! Thanks a lot. Only one additional Question for interrest. I am wondering how this works. I do not have any ServerCertificate for an SSL-Connection. (No keystore). Is the Certificate automatically loaded on Client Side ?

Comment: It has some number of default. Please look on the approved answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143360/ssl-certificate-verification-in-java

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you didn't receive the response back is due to a HTTP Redirect 3XX. Wikipedia redirects your HTTP Request. Please try the below source code to fetch Response from Redirected URL. [Please refer How to send HTTP request GET/POST in Java](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/)

```
public static String readfromURLwithRedirect(String url) {
    String response = "";
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
        conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

        System.out.println("Request URL ... " + url);

        boolean redirect = false;

        // normally, 3xx is redirect
        int status = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM
                    || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER) {
                redirect = true;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Response Code ... " + status);

        if (redirect) {

            // get redirect url from "location" header field
            String newUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");

            // get the cookie if need, for login
            String cookies = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");

            // open the new connnection again
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies);
            conn.addRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla");
            conn.addRequestProperty("Referer", "google.com");

            System.out.println("Redirect to URL : " + newUrl);

        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer responseBuffer = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            responseBuffer.append(inputLine);
        }
        in.close();

        System.out.println("URL Content... \n" + responseBuffer.toString());
        response = responseBuffer.toString();
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}
```