# How can I trust a specific self-sign certificates? (Not trust all)

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

How can I set my `HttpsURLConnection` to trust a specific certificate only? Currently my code is set to trust all certificates. But the requirement is to trust only a specific certificate and do not trust the others. How can I do it in Java? I'm using JDK 1.5.

Comment: Is this self-signed certificate valid for the host name in the URL you're trying to contact?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I accept a self-signed certificate with a Java HttpsURLConnection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trust a specific certificate by creating a custom SSLSocketFactory and providing your own TrustManager.  See...

[Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

and

[How can I use different certificates on specific connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

In your TrustManager, you will be handed the certificate chain from the client / server to verify against your specific certificate.

Comment: The first link ("trusting all certificates [...]") is precisely what shouldn't be done (if you want to prevent MITM attacks).

Comment: Bruno is correct.  You should absolutely provide a mechanism for verifying the server / client certificate.

Comment: Thanks! :) Was able to do it using the 2nd link. Yup, if you're trusting all certificates when using https, then https is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Import it into your client truststore.

Comment: @Arci With the keytool. See the JSSE Reference Guide.