# javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Extensions not allowed in v2 certificate

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to create a Java software that connects to a Netgear WAG102 (Access Point) which has to get the connection logs for my wifi network.

my software already works with other Netgear Access Points (WG302v2, for istance), but I can find no way to get it to work with the WAG102.
I keep on receiving a

> javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Extensions not allowed in v2 certificate

while trying to open a secure SSL connection to the AP.

additional info: the certificate sent from the AP expired 1 year ago, so I implemented the infamous "TrustAllCerts" trick, but that alone didn't seem to help.

Google chrome says that the certificate is version v4, but my java software keeps on saying it's version v2, giving then that exception when it checks for the certificate extensions (version v2 doesn't support extensions, as far as I know).

My question is: is there any way to make it work despite of this issue?

here is my code:

```
private HttpsURLConnection createConnection(URL url) throws IOException{
HttpsURLConnection con=(HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + "**********");
con.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier(){public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session){return true;}});
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts=null;
SSLContext sslContext=null;
SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory;
try{
    trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{ new X509TrustManager(){
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers(){return null;}
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType){}
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType){}
    }};
    sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance( "SSL" );
    sslContext.init( null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom() );
    sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();
    con.setSSLSocketFactory( sslSocketFactory );
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
    System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
    Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
    for(Certificate cert : certs){
        System.out.println("Cert ext : "+cert);
        System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
        System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : " + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
        System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : " + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
        System.out.println("\n");
    }
} catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
//printHTTPSCert(con);
return con;
}
```

I'm getting the exception when calling `con.getResponseCode()`, basically because it's when the connection is getting opened I think.

This program works correctly with www.google.com and all the other sites with a good certificate.

Comment: I'm pretty sure, yes (or at least google chrome says that!). link to screenshot: [link](http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/9250/prettysure.png)

Comment: If there's nothing private in this certificate (perhaps a Subject you wouldn't want to disclose or similar), it would be interesting to see it, if you could paste its PEM (Base64 encoded) version ("copy to file" should allow you to export this).

Comment: here it is: [link] (http://fabrizioroman.altervista.org/certificate/certificate.cer)

Comment: I would take it up with Netgear. It must be a pretty old model if the certificate has expired, so they have probably had many years to have the issue reported before. There will be a firmware upgrade.

Comment: @EJP I'm the admin of a network which is not under my property. I can't buy new stuff, I have to use the APs I already have. In fact the software I'm creating will be used to automatically find and solve network problems just like it does for the other models of AP this network is using. btw: no new firmware upgrade, I have already installed the newest :)

Comment: @user1557092 None of that means you shouldn't take it up with Netgear.

Comment: I think the same about Netgear ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be two issues here:

- Firstly, there it shouldn't be a V4 certificate. It's possible to put this number in the version field, with custom made tools, but there's no specification that matches it. The latest [X.509 specification](http://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-X.509-200811-I/en) only goes up to V3:

  ```
  Version ::= INTEGER { v1(0), v2(1), v3(2) }
  ```
- Secondly, [the Java code that reads the certificate](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/security/x509/X509CertInfo.java) uses a `!=` condition:

  ```
  (version.compare(CertificateVersion.V3) != 0)
  ```

  If it's not V3, it assumes that it's V2 (which makes sense if you consider there shouldn't be a V4). I presume other implementations might let this incorrect certificate through using a `>=` condition instead.

The easiest would be to install a new, correct certificate on the router if possible. (According to your screenshot, it's also using an MD5 signature, which isn't recommended nowadays.)

**EDIT:** It also appears that this certificate was issued with a `www.netgear.com` Subject Alternative Name (i.e. it's valid for that host name), which is non-sense on a router. You should really install your own certificate if you're deploying this, even if it's self-signed.

Anyway, there might be a workaround. It seems that the BouncyCastle implementation `CertificateFactory` (used by the JSSE) is more flexible in terms of versions. If you use the BC provider in a position before the Sun providers, this should work. You can get the BC provider jar and use this (before making connections), for example:

```
Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
```

Comment: I can't install a new certificate on the AP :(
I have to find a workaround! btw, I found that "(version.compare(CertificateVersion.V3) != 0)" thing too, and I even tried to use a modified implementation of it, but it turned out to take much more time than what I expected..

Comment: PEOPLE OF THE INTERNET! A STATUE MUST BE BUILT IN HIS HONOR! it works! Bruno, you are a pro! thank you very much! (I have to fix a HTTP error code 500 now, but it's not a big problem to me)

Comment: I should also add that you should also avoid to use a trust manager that trusts everything to avoid MITM attacks. You could implement one that wraps the default TM and catches the `CertificateExpiredException` instead. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/372643) is also useful to allow specific certificates. You'll almost certainly need a custom host name verifier considering this problems with certificate. (You'll certainly have problems with potential MITM attacks anyway, if Netgear ships all the routers of that model with the same cert, and if you can't reconfigure it...)

Comment: yeah, I already thought about that! thanks for your concern ;)