# Need advice on Self-Signed SSL and Java

Tags: encryption, ssl, self-signed

Issues have been asked many times about how to handle self-signed certificates with Java and implementations are often provided. However, I'm not sure that these implementations will give me the security/trust I am looking for.

My circumstance is as follows: I have a client program connecting to our server application. Both of these we have complete control over. Our client post's a stream using https to a URL at our server, and the server responds. Currently (and this is what I'm trying to fix) the server has a self signed certificate. Java doesn't like this and FOR TESTING ONLY, we are pretty much ignoring the certificate altogether by trusting any certificate.

I have little knowledge of SSL. My boss says we can use our self-signed certificate and it will be secure as long we don't make our crypt. key public. This sounds correct to me, but a lot of posts say self-signed cert's are automatically vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks. Does this mean SSL sends the crypt. key along with the certificate?

Since we have control over both ends, should we just encrypt our data ourselves with a secret key, and decrypt it at the end using our key? Or is there reason to use SSL?

Comment: Not an expert in this area, but I believe you could avoid a man-in-the-middle attack if you demand a particular public key from the certificate (rather than trusting self-signed or signed by a particular issuer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trusting any certificate blindly (which would make the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks), configure your Java client to trust that particular certificate. Self-signed certificates do not inherently make SSL/TLS connections vulnerable to MITM attacks, they just make their distribution and the evaluation of trust more specific to this particular deployment (i.e. you have to configure it manually).

You can do this in at least 3 ways (pick the easiest one for you, I'd suggest bullet point #2):

- Import the server certificate into your client's global trust store (`lib/security/cacerts` in your JRE directory). This will make all applications run with this JRE trust this certificate.
- Import the server certificate into another truststore (possibly a local copy of `lib/security/cacerts`) and make this particular application use this truststore. This can be done using the `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system properties.
- Make your client application use an `SSLContext` initialised with an `X509TrustManager` configured to trust that certificate: either something written manually or a trust manager coming from `TrustManagerFactory` initialised by loading a local keystore that contains that particular certificate (as in the previous method).

You'll find more details about all this in the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Customization).

([This answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/372643) should give you the details for doing all this properly, in particular `keytool -import ...`.)

Comment: It doesn't seem realistic to use the keytool to modify the keystore, since this is outside the code base. I'd like to have it during runtime so after run-time the certificate isn't in the keystore.

Comment: You can use the 3rd method (see erickson's answer in the link) and load your trust store from a new keystore loaded from an input stream coming from your classpath if you want to distribute it with your code. The 2nd method isn't normally a big deal, as I said, make a local copy of `cacerts` (or create a new keystore) and set the system property only for that application. It doesn't have to be a file that affects all your applications. It's just configuration, and you'll have to configure this one way or another anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments against self signed certificates mainly apply to web-applications. Since with the current infrastructure a browser won't be able to validate your self-signed certificate.

Since you have control over the client, you can simply hardcode the certificate you expect into the client. For example you might calculate the sha1 hash of the certificate, and check if that matches the expected value. That way you don't even need to trust hundreds of CAs.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve secure communication you need to first ensure your talking to the right computer.  When the client first attempts to establish a secure connection, it pings the server and the server responds with its cert.   At this point you **MUST validate the servers cert before continuing**.  The cert includes a public key and signature that can be used to ensure the cert is valid.  For example, in web browsers this means checking to see it's been signed by an authority listed as trusted in your browser settings, if that check fails you'll see red warnings in your browser. In your case this will mean you have manually (or in code) added the servers cert into a trust store so that it is trusted.