# Downloading files over HTTPS with unverified SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl

My Java program uses GitHub's raw address to access a version file to get the latest version. This address is in the format https://raw.github.com/user/repository/branch/version_file

During testing stages, I had no problems using this with the following code:

```
currentVersion = new Version(plugin.getDescription().getVersion());

URL url = new URL("https://raw.github.com/zonedabone/CommandSigns/master/VERSION");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
newestVersion = new Version(in.readLine());

if (currentVersion.compareTo(newestVersion) < 0)
    newAvailable = true;
```

However, some users have complained of the following error:

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException:
  PKIX path building failed:
    sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException:
      unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Java is complaining that it can't validate the SSL certificate. GitHub's certificate is verified by DigiCert, but apparently some Java builds won't identify this.

I have read there are two ways to overcome this: adding the certificate to the TrustStore and disabling the validation altogether.

The answers suggested on StackOverflow either make use of an allow-all TrustStore, which would be a really bad idea considering it's not within bounds of a 'test environment', or if they show how to add the certificate, they usually link to a broken web page.

Can somebody provide new information?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered _countless_ times on SO and the web in general.  Please do a Google search on "java self-signed certificate" and delete this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I accept a self-signed certificate with a Java HttpsURLConnection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

Comment: @JimGarrison, true, unfortunately that google search will lead to a number of answers that suggest using a trust manager that trusts any cert...

Comment: @Bruno Agreed, I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: @JimGarrison Might not be a duplicate. The question wasn't actually asking about a self-signed certificate, but one signed by DigiCert; and "DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA" (with thumbprint 5f b7 ee 06 ...)  is in Java's cacerts file, according to "keytool -list". So it should have worked, and something else is going wrong that isn't explained by the current answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First the theory... As the [JSSE Reference Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html) says:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: The JDK ships with a limited number of trusted root
>   certificates in the /lib/security/cacerts file. As
>   documented in keytool, it is your responsibility to maintain (that is,
>   add/remove) the certificates contained in this file if you use this
>   file as a truststore.
>
> Depending on the certificate configuration of the servers you contact,
>   you may need to add additional root certificate(s). Obtain the needed
>   specific root certificate(s) from the appropriate vendor.

Users should maintain the list of CA certificates themselves. A number of people won't know how to do it, unfortunately. They could use another JRE's `cacerts` file (more recent) into their own installation.

You could use a trust manager that trusts any certificate and use it specifically for that connection, but that's not a good idea, since it opens the connection to potential MITM attacks. There are enough examples of code for this insecure solution around.

The best solution, if you want to trust a specific certificate, is to load it correctly using a specific truststore, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/372643). You could even load this trust store from an `InputStream` from the classloader if you want to bundle it with your application.

Alternatively, where possible, you could use the OS trust store directly. On Windows, you can load the `Windows-ROOT` keystore as described in [this article](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/security/). On OSX, you can load a `KeychainStore`.

Comment: The first solution you suggested seems quite reasonable. I'm now away for a week so I'll have to let the other plugin developer to take a look at this before I accept it. The second answer wouldn't be possible as the plugin is non operating system dependent.

Answer (score -2):

You can implement an HttpsUrlConnection with "all"-TrustManager

like http://bitsandcodes.blogspot.de/2010/08/create-trust-manager-that-trust-all-ssl.html

Comment: Are there any better examples? This one uses deprecated types such as SSLContext and uses JSSESocketFactory which cant be resolved in my IDE.

Comment: Edit: the types aren't deprecated, I was just making the wrong imports. However, I still can't use JSSESocketFactory as I am not using org.apache.

Comment: That `JSSESocketFactory` is specific to Axis, which has nothing to do with the question. In addition, it's a bad idea to trust all certificates blindly.