# Using Self Signed certificate in java

Tags: java, certificate, httprequest, sms-gateway, self-signed

I want to connect to a sms gateway. I found the following code.

```
public void smsSender(String username, String password, String to,
        String text) throws IOException {

    try {
        String data = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password
                + "&to=" + to + "&text=" + text;

        URL url = new URL("https://sendsms.abc.com:1010/sms.php");

        HttpURLConnection urlc = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlc.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlc.setDoOutput(true);
        urlc.setRequestProperty("Content-type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        BufferedWriter br = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                urlc.getOutputStream()));

        br.write(data);
        br.flush();

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                urlc.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while (null != ((line = rd.readLine()))) {
            output = line;
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        rd.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When i try to connect using this method Eclipse sends an error message.

> unable to find valid certification path to requested target

The server that i'm trying to access is using self signed certificate. I'm new to this field. How can i solve this problem. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Maybe this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make remote method invocations over SSL, a client needs to trust the certificate of the server. As you said the server has a self-signed certificate, you client needs to be explicitly configured to trust the certificate else the connection fails. 
  To create a trust relationship between a client and server's self-signed certificate, follow the steps mentioned below,

1. First you should get the server certificate on your client side.
   For that the way I know of is, i.e. hit the server url in a browser
   and get the server's certificate and import it in the browser. There might be other ways of getting the server certificate
   but you'll have to explore.
2. Now export the public key as a certificate from the browser to the
   client. let it be server.cer.
3. Now, create the client keystore

   > keytool -genkey -alias clientkeys  -keyalg RSA -keystore
   >   client.keystore -storepass 123456 -keypass 123456 -dname
   >   "CN=localhost, OU=MYOU, O=MYORG, L=MYCITY, S=MYSTATE, C=MY"
4. create the client certificate

   > keytool -export -alias clientkeys -keystore client.keystore -storepass
   >   123456 -file client.cer
5. Now, import the server certificate to the client trust store.

   > keytool -import -alias serverCert -keystore client.truststore
   >   -storepass clientcert -file server.cer
6. now load the client keystore as mentioned in erickson's comment in
   the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection) provided by Werner.

Let me know if things are still not clear. But I suggest you read some documentation on google related to SSL Handshaking between a client and a server.

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide some links for those steps as I'm new here. :)

Comment: Updated my answer. Have a look.

Comment: Still the same problem is there. **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**