# Response failing over HTTPS in Java

Tags: java, ssl, https

We run crawlers on websites to keep our info up to date. Some websites like this [one](https://www.capitallightingfixture.com/) allow standard navigation with the browser, but they don't send responses when using standard Java libraries. Here's the code I'm using to access the home (index) page,

```
    try
    {
        URL my_url = new URL("https://www.capitallightingfixture.com");

        URLConnection u = my_url.openConnection();

        if ( u instanceof HttpURLConnection )
        {
            HttpURLConnection http_u = (HttpURLConnection)u;

            System.out.println(http_u.getResponseCode());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When run, this program will throw the following error

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

From what I understand about the errors, they're thrown when Java can't validate the certificate provided by the server. However, as I mentioned above, Google Chrome has no problems navigating to the page, and it even verifies the certificate (no security errors are thrown).

Is there a way I can override Java and allow it to receive the response anyway?

Comment: Please read the following topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875467/java-client-certificates-over-https-ssl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed Error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9619030/resolving-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-sun-security-validator-validatore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ip you are trying to access is using the self signed certificate. Try the following two links.

[How can I use different certificates on specific connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection)

[Using Self Signed certificate in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13015910/using-self-signed-certificate-in-java)