# I want to access a website but I can't understand what is the problem that is preventing me from doing so

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access this specific website www.srtr.org . My goal is to obtain the address of all the transplant centers. I am currently having some problems accessing the website. My codes are:

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.srtr.org"
page = requests.get(url)
```

I am having some troubles accessing the website. This is the error message that I am reading, can anyone explain or direct me to the correct source to understand where my problem lies and how to solve it?

> Error                                     Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py
> in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect,
> suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
> 437             try:
> --> 438                 cnx.do_handshake()
> 439             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py in
> do_handshake(self)    1637         result =
> _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
> -> 1638         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)    1639
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py in
> _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)    1377         else:
> -> 1378             _raise_current_error()    1379
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py in
> exception_from_error_queue(exception_type)
> 53
> ---> 54     raise exception_type(errors)
> 55
>
> Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate
> verify failed')]
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
> in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
> assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
> body_pos, **response_kw)
> 599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
> --> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
> 601
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
> in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked,
> **httplib_request_kw)
> 344         try:
> --> 345             self._validate_conn(conn)
> 346         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
> in _validate_conn(self, conn)
> 843         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
> --> 844             conn.connect()
> 845
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py
> in connect(self)
> 325             server_hostname=hostname,
> --> 326             ssl_context=context)
> 327
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py
> in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs,
> server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
> 324     if HAS_SNI:  # Platform-specific: OpenSSL with enabled SNI
> --> 325         return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
> 326
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py
> in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect,
> suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
> 444             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
> --> 445                 raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
> 446             break
>
> SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py
> in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
> 437                     retries=self.max_retries,
> --> 438                     timeout=timeout
> 439                 )
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py
> in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect,
> assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked,
> body_pos, **response_kw)
> 629             clean_exit = False
> --> 630             raise SSLError(e)
> 631
>
> SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in ()
> 3
> 4 url = "https://www.srtr.org"
> ----> 5 page = requests.get(url)
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in
> get(url, params, **kwargs)
> 70
> 71     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
> ---> 72     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
> 73
> 74
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py in
> request(method, url, **kwargs)
> 56     # cases, and look like a memory leak in others.
> 57     with sessions.Session() as session:
> ---> 58         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
> 59
> 60
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py
> in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files,
> auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert,
> json)
> 516         }
> 517         send_kwargs.update(settings)
> --> 518         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
> 519
> 520         return resp
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py
> in send(self, request, **kwargs)
> 637
> 638         # Send the request
> --> 639         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
> 640
> 641         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)
>
> /Users/nghl/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py
> in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
> 510         except (_SSLError, _HTTPError) as e:
> 511             if isinstance(e, _SSLError):
> --> 512                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
> 513             elif isinstance(e, ReadTimeoutError):
> 514                 raise ReadTimeout(e, request=request)
>
> SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines',
> 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",)

Comment: This is due to the ssl certificate verification failed. Most likely the cert expired or the website using non-trusted CA cert. You can bypass it using `page = requests.get(url, verify=False)`, but this is not recommended due to the security risks that could impose.

Comment: Thanks. Can I get know what kind of security risk are you referring to?

Comment: @HanNg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13076511/security-risks-in-disabling-ssl-certification-for-java-program