# Java SSL connection with self-signed certificate without copying complete keystore to client

Tags: java, servlets, ssl, https, keytool

I am setting up a licensing servlet in Java together with a client app that will post request for new licenses and validate existing licenses at that server. The servlet runs in Tomcat. I've configured Tomcat so that it only allows connections to the servlet over https, and this works just fine.

I have created a self-signed certificate using `'keytool -genkey -alias www.mysite.com -keyalg RSA -keystore license.store'` which creates a file `license.store` and pointed tomcat to this keystoreFile with its password `asdf1234`.

When I just try to connect from the client to the servlet over https in Java, I receive the familiar `PKIX path building failed` because the certificate is not in the truststore. I tried to fixed this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/859271) suggestion resulting in the code below:

```
private SSLSocketFactory getSSLFactory() throws Exception {

    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("license.store");

    if(is ==null) {
        return null;
    }

    keyStore.load(is, "asdf1234".toCharArray());
    is.close();

    TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(keyStore);

    SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);

    return ctx.getSocketFactory();
}
```

After which I call:

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
con.setSSLSocketFactory(getSSLFactory());
```

which results in a succesfull connection.

Now the problem is that I only get this to work when I copy the `license.store` to the client and load that into the `KeyStore.load()`. It doesn't strike me as very safe to copy the private key and its password that the server uses to the client. Is there any way to extract only the public key from the license.store and use that? I've been searching this forum and others for a day now and just can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be generating a public-private key pair, but rather import the certificate of the server into your (the client's) Java truststore. The certificate is not a secret, and thus does not provide a security risk on the client side. See the `-import` option for keytool. Here's in an [example](http://www.chrissearle.org/blog/technical/adding_self_signed_https_certificates_java_keystore).

Comment: I finally got it! The thing was that I first had to _export_ the certificate from the keystore: _keystore -export -alias www.mysite.com -file license.cer -keystore license.store_
and then import the exported certificate into a new keystore using
_keystore -import -alias whatever -file license.cer -keystore client.store_. The client.store is then copied to the client, which is read in the KeyStore as in the example above.