# Import certificate by java keytool

Tags: java, import, certificate, keystore, keytool

I use Java keytool and I want to do something simple but have a problem after fifth step. What's wrong here?

1. Side "A" creates public and private key:

   **keytool -genkeypair -alias AStore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -dname -keypass Aaa123 -validity 90 -storetype JCEKS -keystore D:\keystore\A\keystore.jceks -storepass Aaa123**
2. Side "B" creates public and private key:

   **keytool -genkeypair -alias BStore -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -dname -keypass Bbb123 -validity 90 -storetype JCEKS -keystore D:\keystore\B\keystore.jceks -storepass Bbb123**
3. Side "A" export his certificate:

   **keytool -exportcert -alias AStore -file D:\keystore\A.cer -keystore D:\keystore\A\keystore.jceks -storetype JCEKS**
4. Side "B" export his certificate:

   **keytool -exportcert -alias BStore -file D:\keystore\B.cer -keystore D:\keystore\B\keystore.jceks -storetype JCEKS**
5. Side "A" import certificate of side "B":

   **keytool -importcert -alias AStore -file D:\keystore\B.cer -keystore D:\keystore\A\keystore.jceks -storetype JCEKS**

I get error:

**> keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Public keys in reply and keystore don't match**

Comment: hope this will help:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17083119/error-while-importing-public-certificate-to-a-keystore

Comment: In step 1 and 2, after -dname a valid dname must be added, for example CN=A and CN=B

Comment: Yes. My problem that in first and fifth steps I used the same alias. And this is solution