# Having Problem Installing SSL Certificate to Java Keystore

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, https, keytool

I am using the following steps to generate **Keystore** and then corresponding **CSR**, then have sent the **CSR** to **godaddy** for signing and received respective certificate files. But when I try to import the received **.crt** file to the keystore i get

**"keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply does not contain public key for "**.

Following are the list of steps that i followed in the process.

1.keytool -genkey -alias server -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore your_site_name.jks (and then added the reqquired information)

2.keytool -certreq -alias server -file csr.txt -keystore your_site_name.jks

// sent the csr to godaddy and received the crt files

3.keytool -import -alias server -file your_site_name.crt -keystore your_site_name.jks

// this is the step in which the am getting the above error

**"keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Certificate reply does not contain public key for ".**

Comment: From [duplicate answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17083692/5221149) step 4 (your step 3): *important that this has an **alias different** to step 1*.

Comment: are you implying that the steps given in godaddy official website are not correct?

https://in.godaddy.com/help/java-code-signing-generate-a-csr-4780

Comment: https://www.adfdesign.com/blog/2019/01/26/installing-an-ssl-cert-from-godaddy-on-tomcat-9-server-running-on-windows-2012r2/

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/keytool-commandutility-to-generate-a-keystorecerti

Comment: GoDaddy steps are good. Steps 1 and 2 (see [Generate a CSR](https://in.godaddy.com/help/java-code-signing-generate-a-csr-4780)) uses `-alias codesigncert`, and step 3 (see [Download certificate & sign code](https://in.godaddy.com/help/java-code-signing-download-certificate-and-sign-code-20273)) **has no `-alias`**, hence gets assigned some other alias.

Comment: The problem seemed to be this...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052700/java-io-ioexception-invalid-keystore-format/62467748#62467748