# jsoup posting Java

Tags: java, jsoup

Im struggling getting java submitting POST requests over HTTPS

Code used is here

```
     try{
        Response res = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_URL)
    .data("username", "blah", "password", "blah")

    .method(Method.POST)
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0")
                .header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
                .execute();
        System.out.println(res.body());
        System.out.println("Code " +res.statusCode());

        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
        }
```

and also this

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(LOGIN_URL)
  .data("username", "blah")
  .data("password", "blah")
  .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0")
        .header("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
         .method(Method.POST)
  .timeout(3000)
  .post();
```

Where LOGIN_URL = https://xxx.com/Login?val=login

When used over HTTP it seems to work, HTTPS it doesnt, But doesnt throw any exceptions

How can I POST over HTTPS

Edit:

seems there is a 302 redirect involved when the server gets a POST over HTTPS  (which doesnt happen over http) How can I use jsoup to store the cookie sent with the 302 to the next page ?

Comment: Can you check the server log? Likely it's a problem with the server certificate. You can try [to import it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/859271/315306) and see if is solves your problem

Comment: Added the key and put this in the code System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "sitename.jks");
still not working as expected

Comment: making similar code in PHP, Cookies between requests need to be handled (302 redirect after the post) How do i enable this in jsoup ?

Comment: Use [`followRedirects`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html) before `execute()`

Comment: set to false you mean ?

Comment: No. If you want the HTTP client to follow the redirects...

Comment: Its set to true by default.

Comment: Can you give the link? Or the server code?

Comment: trying to login to lite.betfair.com, Non API method as i dont have enought credits on my account for that, php+curl works fine, I would just prefer java

Comment: Possibly to do with secure cookies. There is a redirect to a non secure page then a redirect to a secure page, I assume curl will respect that ?

Comment: i have faced the same issue. then i have used `HttpURLConnection` and it works. if u want to use `HttpURLConnection` i can show u what i have done.

Comment: That would be great. I'll look in to it myself as well. Thanks

Comment: @shoshi can you post as an answer so i can accept, Its working

Comment: @user1281385 : i have posted my answer. thankx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my code:

```
URL form = new URL(Your_url);
connection1 = (HttpURLConnection)form.openConnection();
connection1.setRequestProperty("Cookie", your_cookie);

connection1.setReadTimeout(10000);
StringBuilder whole = new StringBuilder();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(connection1.getInputStream())));
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
     whole.append(inputLine);
     in.close();
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(whole.toString());
String title = doc.title();
```

i have used this code to get the title of the new page.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try...

```
import org.jsoup.Connection;


Connection.Response res = null;
    try {
        res = Jsoup
                .connect("your-first-page-link")
                .data("username", "blah", "password", "blah")
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now save all your cookies and make a request to the other page you want.

```
//Saving Cookies
cookies = res.cookies();
```

Making a request to another page.

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("your-second-page-link").cookies(cookies).get();
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment if further help needed.