# CertificateException - OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException

Tags: android, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have the following code in my android project where i am connecting to secured server. 
I am getting the parse error. [pasted below] .if anyone knows about this exception, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Code Snippet

```
CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/storage/emulated/0/cert.p12"));
Certificate ca;
try {
    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);   // error at this line
    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
} finally {
    caInput.close();
}
```

Error

```
01-15 17:01:00.107: W/System.err(14932): java.security.cert.CertificateException:   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory$ParsingException: java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag
01-15 17:01:00.107: W/System.err(14932):    at   com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.engineGenerateCertificate(OpenSSLX509CertificateFactory.java:272)
```

01-15 17:01:00.107: W/System.err(14932):    at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:195)

Comment: Try the BouncyCastle provider (i.e, `getInstance("X.509", "BC");` Also ensure your version of Android is not too old. See, for example, [Android fails converting p12 file's certificates to x509; converts properly using java](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/HCiHwBKOsrI).

Comment: @noloader, your comment is worthy of an answer. I did exactly that (Adding the BC provider) and it worked. You should add it as an answer to help others.

Comment: 1. Seems to a wrong file format. For openssl threre is DER and PEM type. Try to convert your cert.p12 to another format ($ x509 -in cert.p12 -inform PEM –out output.crt -outform DER).

Answer (score 15):

I found the solution to this same problem. Include the "BC" provider to this line of code, and the error could disappear: `getInstance("X.509", "BC")`

Comment: @ Josh how we can add this

Comment: Hi @Amitsharma , that code is for the TrustManager instance. You can find some ideas, in the answer I posted for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-can-i-use-different-certificates-on-specific-connections/34533740#34533740

Comment: After doing this X.509 not found